# Correct (App Store Safe) way to resign a first responder?

Tags: iphone

What's the correct way to resign the current firstResponder?

I've seen the following:
Looping through fields and calling resignFirstResponder on each.

```
[[self textFieldForRow:0] resignFirstResponder];
[[self textFieldForRow:1] resignFirstResponder];
[[self textFieldForRow:2] resignFirstResponder];
[[self textFieldForRow:3] resignFirstResponder];
```

And this which looks like it's calling a private function, is this app store safe?:

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIView   *firstResponder = [keyWindow performSelector:@selector(firstResponder)];   
[firstResponder resignFirstResponder];
```

Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comments:
Looks like the second method is using a private api and someone's app has been rejected because of it: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/how-do-i-legally-get-the-current-first-responder-on-the-screen-on-an-iphone)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's actually an API to do this:

[view endEditing:YES];

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/endEditing:

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this question: [How do I [legally] get the current first responder on the screen on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/how-do-i-legally-get-the-current-first-responder-on-the-screen-on-an-iphone)

My answer to that question should work perfectly in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have up there is not calling any private function. What is happening is:

```
 //Gets the application window
 UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
 //Gets the first Responder View for the window
UIView   *firstResponder = [keyWindow performSelector:@selector(firstResponder)];  
//Make the UView resign the first responder 
[firstResponder resignFirstResponder];
```

All of those are public functions, so you will not have any problem with the app store as far as I know.

Additionally is there a better way to do what exactly?. If you are talking about getting the UIView that is the firstResponder to the keyWindow, you could do when creating your uiview:

```
myView.tag = 100;
```

and to get it:

```
UIView *firstResponder = [self viewWithTag:100];
```

Comment: I don't see "firstResponder" defined as a property or a method in the UIWindow documentation?

Comment: UIWindow->UIView->UIResponder->isFirstResponder  (that's the inheritance chain leading to the method).  Don't forget to look at superclass methods...

Comment: You are correct it is not defined as a method in the UIWindow documentation, but it is defined in UIResponder (inherited)

Comment: isFirstResponder is: - (BOOL)isFirstResponder, firstResponder is completely different and NOT a BOOL.  There it a firstResponder variable in the UIWindow.h header but it is defined as private:  UIResponder *_firstResponder;

Comment: Is that code actually working for you?. I am thinking maybe firstResponder is just a custom method. I did just see that variable declared in UIWindow.h, but there is no accessor for it.

Comment: Yes it works but it doesn't mean it'll pass the app store approval process.  A variable that starts with a _ usually means it is a private variable not meant to be used outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to implement a hacky & slow version of firstResponder yourself in a category and then file a radar requesting they add the method. Something along these lines:

```
- (id)my_FirstResponder
    for view in [self subviews]
        if [self isFirstResponder]
            return self
        return [self my_firstResponder]
    return nil
```

Using `performSelector:` to invoke a method not in the public headers is definitely grounds for rejection, so don't do that. Oh, and don't forget to use a prefix (like the above code does) when adding a category to avoid conflicts.