# Three20 UITextView/UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

What is the equivalent of a UITextView/UILabel in Three20? I would like to have a functionality of detecting URL's just like UITextView, however I want it to respond to swipe and touch events, not like UITextView, wonder if Three20 supports this?? It also needs to have multiline support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TTStyledTextLabel](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_styled_text_label.php)

You can find an example in TTCatalog (folder "samples"):

[image]

Comment: if you put this inside a cell can you tap on it?

Comment: yes, a TTStyledTextLabel is a UIView, so you can put it inside a cell of a UITableView. You can add touch events an every view in this way: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660371/509535