# UITapGestureRecognizer not working on simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface, ios-simulator

Just started iOS programming, trying to get UITapGestureRecognizer working using iOS 5.1 simulator, and i can't seem to get the right values when tapping. here's my code that i took from nathan eror's answer to [nathan eror](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100039/nathan-eror)'s [How to add a touch event to a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660371/how-to-add-a-touch-event-to-a-uiview)

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];

    NSLog(@"touched points: %g, %g", location.x, location.y);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    NSLog(@"gets in here");
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
}
```

and i keep getting 0.000000 for my values every time i tap on the trackpad on my macbook pro on the simulator. is it because of the simulator? or am i doig something morbidly wrong?

P.S does anyone know how to highlight the code as objective-C in posting this question? thnx in advance

Comment: When you say "tap on the trackpad", do you actually mean _click_, or really _tap_? A click on the simulator window gets treated as a tap inside the simulator. Taps on the physical trackpad have no significance to the simulator -- they don't get passed on, AFAIK.

Comment: @DavidT The site will automatically highlight your code as Objective-C if your question is tagged Objective-C.  However, the editor preview usually doesn't highlight in real-time.

Comment: @W'rkncacnter gotcha. umm... i guess more like "click" on the trackpad. so it was simulating the "tap" on simulator

Comment: @robmayoff gotcha, thanks, and no wonder.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce your problem.  It appears to happen because `[recognizer.view superview]` is the window (class `UIWindow`).  Although `UIWindow` is a subclass of `UIView`, the gesture recognizer doesn't seem to convert the location to the window's coordinate system correctly.  If I add a subview to `self.view` and put the gesture recognizer on that subview, it converts the point to `self.view`'s coordinate system correctly.

I suggest you file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com.  (The product is “iPhone SDK”.)

If you really need to get the point in the window's coordinate system, you can do this:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
    location = [recognizer.view convertPoint:location toView:recognizer.view.superview];

    NSLog(@"touched point: %g, %g", location.x, location.y);
}
```

However, the window's coordinate system includes space for the status bar, and doesn't rotate when you rotate the device.  It's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try NSLog(@"touched point %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(location))