# Closures for UIGestureRecognizers

Tags: ios, swift, closures, uigesturerecognizer

I was wondering, whether it is possible to initialize a `UIGestureRecognizer` with a block, instead of having to create a separate function for it.
In Swift 3, I believe, this was introduced for timers.

I've implemented something similar to the code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26287183/3397217) since it didn't work for me.
This is my code:

```
class TapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    private var closure: (() -> ())?

    init() {
        super.init(target: TapGestureRecognizer.self, action: #selector(self.runAction))
    }

    convenience init(for view: UIView, block: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
        self.init()
        closure = block
        view.addGestureRecognizer(self)
    }

    func runAction() {
        print("executed")
        if closure == nil { return }
        closure!()
    }    
}
```

When I create a `TapGestureRecognizer` like this:

```
TapGestureRecognizer(block: { _ in
    print("tapped")
})
```

... I get the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[MyApp.TapGestureRecognizer runAction]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x105941598'

Any idea why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIGestureRecognizer with closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223944/uigesturerecognizer-with-closure)

Comment: I don't believe there is a built-in way to do this that is a public API, but you can build your own using the linked post.

Comment: I've edited my question @JAL

Comment: Retracted my close vote and added an answer.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43485387/6680583

Comment: @Mannopson I don't see how that's relevant to the issue here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is your target is on on the `TapGestureRecognizer` *class* itself. Your `runAction` method is an *instance* method, but you're telling the `super.init` that it's a class method, thus the failure here: `+[MyApp.TapGestureRecognizer runAction]`.  You can fix this by making `runAction` a class method.

You could also remove the target on class and add the instance after initialization:

```
init() {
    super.init(target: TapGestureRecognizer.self, action: #selector(runAction))
    self.removeTarget(TapGestureRecognizer.self, action: #selector(runAction))
    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(runAction))
}
```

Or you could somehow wrap the closure to be fired in a different object.

Comment: If I automatically add it to the view inside the `convenience init` the compiler gives the warning that the *"Result of initializer is unused"*. (It still works though, obviously.) Any idea how to mute it? I'd rather not manually add it to the view when creating it... Also `let _ = ` wouldn't be the perfect solution.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I don't get that warning with this code in Xcode 8.3: `view.addGestureRecognizer(TapGestureRecognizer(block: { _ in print("tapped") }))`

Comment: Right. I was talking about code like this: `TapGestureRecognizer(for: view, block: { _ in print("tapped") })` which automatically adds the recognizer to the view inside its init function.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth That code isn't in your question.  Edit your question to include the updated initializer code with `for: view`.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth All `init` methods return an instance of an object.  If you just want to make a convenience method which adds a gesture recognizer to a view, use a void function, not an initializer.

Comment: As an optimization: doesn't swift figure out itself to convert that instance method to a class method? I guess I'm confusing this optimization mechanism with something else...can't remember what :/

Comment: @Honey I'm not sure what you're asking.  If the target is `TapGestureRecognizer.self`, the gesture recognizer is expecting an instance **on that class**.  Review the [initializer docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624211-init), specifically "`target`: An object that is the recipient of action messages sent by the receiver when it recognizes a gesture. nil is not a valid value."  It doesn't matter if a class or instance is used as a target, a message is being sent to whatever it is.

Comment: I wrote my question bad: My question is: why isn't `runAction` a class method? Because it doesn't have the `class` before it? OK, I get that! But isn't Swift smart enough...to optimize methods that don't use any property into class methods?

Comment: @Honey why would Swift optimize instance methods into class methods?  That would be a horrible optimization.  The compiler doesn't know how these methods will be called, especially in Objective-C world where any object can send or receive any message, which we are since we're inheriting from `NSObject`.