# How to set IBAction on view obtained from xib

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, ibaction

I have a xib file which I created using `New -> iOS -> User Interface -> View`. Then to inflate/load it into my UIViewController I do

```
UIView *myView = [[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FileName" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil].firstObject;
```

Now that I have the view, I need to know when the user taps on it. How might I set such IBAction (or whatever the appropriate term)?

Comment: You didn't use Storyboard ?

Comment: This is just a view, not a UIViewController. And this is a view that I will dynamically show/hide in UIViewController. So no I didn't use storyboard for that view. But the UIViewController was specified using storyboard.

Comment: If the question seems shallow that's because until now I have always exclusively used the storyboard. This is the first time I am using xib. And I don't know how to get an IBAction connected to the view in the xib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always you set the IBAction in the ViewContoller , so bind the action to the xib by specify the file  owner is the view controller. You also can dynamic add view touch handle by use addGestureRecognizer to handle the event on the view.
exampe in :
[add gesture to the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660371/how-to-add-a-touch-event-to-a-uiview)

Comment: I remember Gesture as complicated. So that's why I just wanted to have an IBAction method. Again, this is a View not a UIViewController. I don't know how to manipulate the xib file to point to an IBAction

Comment: You can see the example:http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/07/30/iphone-programming-tutorial-connecting-code-to-an-interface-builder-view/

Answer (score 0):

There is the `Owner` element in XIBs. AFAIK, only the owner can be used in manual load scenarios.

In the XIB editor, link events to the owner element. When instantiate the XIB, make the `owner` parameter object provide required event handlers.

Comment: by owner do you mean `instantiateWithOwner:`? Or are you referring to a field in "Interface Builder" inspectors?

Comment: I mean, with `instantiateWithOwner:` method, we can provide the owner object on loading. Of course, this owner is the "Interface Builder" inspector Owner.