# How to call gesture tap on UIView programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios8, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIView and and I have added tap gesture to it:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
tap.delegate = self
myView.addGesture(tap)
```

I am trying to call it programmatically in the testfile.

```
sendActionForEvent
```

I am using this function, but it is not working:

```
myView.sendActionForEvent(UIEvents.touchUpDown)
```

It shows unrecognised selector sent to instance.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In swift 2.2 you can use new selector syntax:     let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))

Comment: @wujo - thanks for that; strangely it doesn't actually work for me, in a UIView  Maybe only in a view controller?

Comment: Also remember to have `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true` if you're using an image view. Got caught on that for too long.

Comment: @Josh, yes an important point.

Comment: @George have you found the solution yet? I'm having the same concern with you. But my purpose is for unit test, where I want to trigger the tap on the view. Thanks

Comment: @KhangAzun the best option is to call the tap function directly

Answer (score 333):

You need to initialize `UITapGestureRecognizer` with a target and action, like so:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
myView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Then, you should implement the handler, which will be called each time when a tap event occurs:

```
@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    // handling code
}
```

So now calling your tap gesture recognizer event handler is as easy as calling a method:

```
handleTap()
```

Comment: instead of calling selector function directly, i want to call it by programmatically invoking UITapGestureRecognizer event

Comment: @muhasturk Don't change the meaning of an upvoted answer. Your edit was invalidating the answer for older Swift versions. If you want to post an update for Swift 2.2, post your own answer. Thank you.

Comment: `tap.delegate = self` is not needed, since you already set a target and action

Comment: Throws an error in Swift3, your handle tap function should be: func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)

Comment: Calling function should be................func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) ...............you missed "_"........so your calling function was not working..

Answer (score 125):

For anyone who is looking for **Swift 3** solution

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))

view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

self.view.addSubview(view)

// function which is triggered when handleTap is called
@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     print("Hello World")
  }
```

Comment: `isUserInteractionEnabled` is really necessary? the default is false?

Comment: `view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` is the key when your view is ImageView or any subclass of UIVIew instead of UIControl.

Answer (score 69):

For **Swift 4**:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))

view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

self.view.addSubview(view)

// function which is triggered when handleTap is called
@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Hello World")
}
```

In Swift 4, you need to explicitly indicate that the triggered function is callable from Objective-C, so you need to add @objc too your handleTap function.

See @Ali Beadle 's answer here: [Swift 4 add gesture: override vs @objc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867038/swift-4-add-gesture-override-vs-objc)

Comment: `view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` is the key when your view is ImageView or any subclass of UIVIew instead of UIControl.

Answer (score 52):

Just a note - Don't forget to enabled interaction on the view:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))

view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

// view.userInteractionEnabled = true

self.view.addSubview(view)
```

Comment: The note is important!

Answer (score 28):

Implementing tap gesture

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "touchHappen") 
view.userInteractionEnabled = true
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Calls this function when the tap is recognized.

```
func touchHappen() {
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

**Update for For Swift 3 +**

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.touchHappen(_:)))
yourView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
yourView.userInteractionEnabled = true

func touchHappen(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Hello Dear you are here")
}
```

Answer (score 23):

**STEP : 1**

```
@IBOutlet var viewTap: UIView!
```

**STEP : 2**

```
var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
```

**STEP : 3**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // TAP Gesture
    tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.myviewTapped(_:)))
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    viewTap.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    viewTap.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

**STEP : 4**

```
func myviewTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if self.viewTap.backgroundColor == UIColor.yellow {
        self.viewTap.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }else{
        self.viewTap.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 20):

**Swift 5.1** **Example for three view**

***Step:1*** -> Add storyboard view and add outlet viewController UIView

```
@IBOutlet var firstView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var secondView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var thirdView: UIView!
```

***Step:2*** -> Add storyBoard view Tag

[image: firstView]
[image: secondView]
[image: thirdView]

***Step:3*** -> Add gesture

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        firstView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap(_:))))
        firstView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        secondView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap(_:))))
        secondView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        thirdView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap(_:))))
        thirdView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
```

***Step:4*** -> select view

```
@objc func tap(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let tag = gestureRecognizer.view?.tag
        switch tag! {
        case 1 :
            print("select first view")
        case 2 :
            print("select second view")
        case 3 :
            print("select third view")
        default:
            print("default")
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can delete the lines "isUserInteractionEnabled = true" and put the value directly on Attributes Inspector, just below "Tag" you have "User Interaction Enabled" with a check-box.

Answer (score 13):

Swift 4

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.touchTapped(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

@objc func touchTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
}
```

Answer (score 9):

try the following extension

```swift
extension UIView {
    
    func  addTapGesture(action : @escaping ()->Void ){
        let tap = MyTapGestureRecognizer(target: self , action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
        tap.action = action
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
    }

    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: MyTapGestureRecognizer) {
        sender.action!()
    }
}

class MyTapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    var action : (()->Void)? = nil
}
```

and then use it :

```swift
submitBtn.addTapGesture {
     //your code
}
```

you can even use it for cell

```swift
cell.addTapGesture {
     //your code
}
```

Comment: While a code-only answer is indeed an answer, a bit of explanation (why the OP's code did not work, what is the general idea behind your code, important points, warnings, ...) could make it a *better* answer.

Comment: This has got to be the best answer to the question.

Comment: is memory leak code

Answer (score 8):

This is how it works in Swift 3:

```
@IBOutlet var myView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(handleTap))

    myView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func handleTap() {
    print("tapped")
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Complete answer for Swift 4**

Step 1: create an outlet for the view

```
@IBOutlet weak var rightViewOutlet: UIView!
```

Step 2: define a tap gesture

```
var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
```

Step 3: create ObjC function (called when view tapped)

```
@objc func rightViewTapped(_ recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Right button is tapped")
}
```

Step 4: add the following within viewDidLoad()

```
let rightTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.rightViewTapped(_:)))
    rightViewOutlet.addGestureRecognizer(rightTap)
```

Comment: Step 2 is not required.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the simplest way to add Gestures on View in **Swift 5**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addGestures()
    }

    // MARK: Add Gestures to target view
    func addGestures()
    {
        // 1. Single Tap or Touch
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapGetstureDetected))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        //2. Double Tap
        let doubleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.doubleTapGestureDetected))
        doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGesture)

        //3. Swipe
        let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipeGetstureDetected))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)

        //4. Pinch
        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.pinchGetstureDetected))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)

        //5. Long Press
        let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longPressGetstureDetected))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)

        //6. Pan
        let panGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panGestureDetected))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

    }

    // MARK: Handle Gesture detection
    @objc func swipeGetstureDetected() {
        print("Swipe Gesture detected!!")
    }

    @objc func tapGetstureDetected() {
        print("Touch/Tap Gesture detected!!")
    }

    @objc func pinchGetstureDetected() {
        print("Pinch Gesture detected!!")
    }

    @objc func longPressGetstureDetected() {
        print("Long Press Gesture detected!!")
    }

    @objc func doubleTapGestureDetected() {
        print("Double Tap Gesture detected!!")
    }

    @objc func panGestureDetected()
    {
        print("Pan Gesture detected!!")
    }


    //MARK: Shake Gesture
    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?){
        if motion == .motionShake
        {
            print("Shake Gesture Detected")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I worked out on Xcode 6.4 on swift.  See below.

```
var view1: UIView!

func assignTapToView1() {          
  let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap"))
  //  tap.delegate = self
  view1.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
  self.view .addSubview(view1)

...
}

func handleTap() {
 print("tap working")
 view1.removeFromSuperview()
 // view1.alpha = 0.1
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to initialize UITapGestureRecognizer with a target and action, like so:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
tap.delegate = self
myView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Then, you should implement the handler, which will be called each time when a tap event occurs:

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  // handling code
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want Objective C code is given below,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gesRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)]; // Declare the Gesture.
gesRecognizer.delegate = self;
[yourView addGestureRecognizer:gesRecognizer]; // Add Gesture to your view.

// Declare the Gesture Recognizer handler method.

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
   NSLog(@"Tapped");
}
```

or you want swift code is given below,

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Add tap gesture recognizer to view
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    // this method is called when a tap is recognized
    func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        print("tap")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleFrontTap:"))
    frontView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

// Make sure this is not private
func handleFrontTap(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tap working")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4**

First, create an object of UITapGestureRecognizer

```
var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
```

The second step is to initialise UITapGestureReconizer. Enable the user
   interaction, then add it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.myviewTapped(_:)))
            infosView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            infosView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
view.addSubview(infosView)
}
```

Third, create a method

```
@objc func myviewTapped(_ recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
                print("button is tapped")
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

I worked out on Xcode 7.3.1 on Swift 2.2. See below.

```
func addTapGesture() {
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyViewController.handleTap))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.myView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func handleTap() {
    // Your code here...
}
```

Comment: add `addTapGesture()` in your `viewDidLoad()`

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to specify two points which kept causing me problems.

- I was creating the Gesture Recognizer on init and storing it in a let property. Apparently, adding this gesture recog to the view does not work. May be self object passed to the gesture recognizer during init, is not properly configured.
- The gesture recognizer should not be added to views with zero frames. I create all my views with zero frame and then resize them using autolayout. The gesture recognizers have to be added AFTER the views have been resized by the autolayout engine. So I add the gesture recognizer in viewDidAppear and they work.

Answer (score 1):

xCode 9.3, Swift 4.0

```
class BaseVC: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate { 

      @IBOutlet weak var iView: UIView!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          let clickUITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onSelect(_:)))
          clickUITapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
          iView?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
      }

      func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
          return true
      }


     @IBAction func onSelect(_ sender: Any) {

     }
}
```

Comment: The function onSelect don't need to be IBAction

Comment: iView?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
The name of your gestureRecognizer is clickUITapGestureRecognizer
So the right way is: iView?.addGestureRecognizer(clickUITapGestureRecognizer)

Answer (score 1):

**Inside ViewDidLoad**

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    self.imgMainAdView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.imgMainAdView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

> 

```
//MARK: - Image Tap Method -
@objc func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    print("Tapped")
    if let url = URL(string: self.strMAinAdvLink)
    {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
    }
}
```

> Calling Purpose

```
@IBAction func btnCall1Action(_ sender: Any)
{
    let text = self.strPhoneNumber1!
    let test = String(text.filter { !" -()".contains($0) })
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "tel://\(test)")! as URL)
}
```

> Mail Purpose

```
MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

 @IBAction func btnMailAction(_ sender: Any)
{
    let strEmail = SAFESTRING(str:  (self.dictEventDetails?.value(forKeyPath: "Email.value_text.email") as! String))

    if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()
    {
        AppDelegate.sharedInstance().showAlertAction(strTitle: "OK", strMessage: "Mail services are not available") { (success) in
        }
        return
    }
    let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    composeVC.setToRecipients([strEmail])
    composeVC.setSubject("")
    composeVC.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)
    self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?)
{
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following swift code (tested in Xcode 6.3.1):

```
    import UIKit

    class KEUITapGesture150427 : UIViewController {
      var _myTap: UITapGestureRecognizer?
      var _myView: UIView?

      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();

        _myTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self
, action: Selector("_myHandleTap:"))
        _myTap!.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

        _myView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100))
        _myView!.backgroundColor=UIColor.blueColor()
        _myView!.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        _myView!.layer.borderWidth = 1
        _myView!.addGestureRecognizer(_myTap!)
        view.addSubview(_myView!)
      }

      func _myHandleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .Ended {
          println("_myHandleTap(sender.state == .Ended)")
          sender.view!.backgroundColor
          = UIColor(red: CGFloat(drand48()), green: CGFloat(drand48()), blue: CGFloat(drand48()), alpha: 1.0);
        }
      }
    }
```

Note that your target could be any subclass of UIResponder, see (tested in Xcode 6.3.1):

```
    import UIKit

    class MyTapTarget  : UIResponder {
      func _myHandleTap2(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .Ended {
          println("_myHandleTap2(sender.state == .Ended)")
          sender.view!.backgroundColor
            = UIColor(red: CGFloat(drand48()), green: CGFloat(drand48()), blue: CGFloat(drand48()), alpha: 1.0);
        }
      }
    }

    class KEUITapGesture150427b : UIViewController {
      var _myTap: UITapGestureRecognizer?
      var _myView: UIView?
      var _myTapTarget: MyTapTarget?

      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();

        _myTapTarget = MyTapTarget()
        _myTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: _myTapTarget!
, action: Selector("_myHandleTap2:"))
        _myTap!.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

        _myView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100))
        _myView!.backgroundColor=UIColor.blueColor()
        _myView!.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        _myView!.layer.borderWidth = 1
        _myView!.addGestureRecognizer(_myTap!)
        view.addSubview(_myView!)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of invoking myView's UITapGestureRecognizer, you can directly call the `handleTap` function,

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to activate a views tap gesture recognizer without having direct access to the gesture recognizer... when returning to a page I had to fill bubbles that were previously filled by tapping. I kept track of those bubbles tags (bubs) ...

```
func fillBubs(bubs: [Int]) {
    for bub in bubs {
        let bubble = view.viewWithTag(bub)
        if bubble == nil {continue}
        for g in bubble!.gestureRecognizers! {
            let tap = g as! UITapGestureRecognizer
            handleBub(tap)
        }
    }
}

@objc func handleBub(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    let bubble = sender?.view!
    bubble?.layer.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
}
```