# Adding Tap Gesture to any view triggers nothing

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uikit, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am dealing with the single most frustrating issue so far in my journey to iOS development. I originally was trying to add a gesture recognizer to my `UIImage` view but was not having any luck. I did some searching on stack and found that I hadn't set `imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` which I figured would solve my problem but it didn't. So then I started adding gesture recognizers to everything including the parent view of `imageView` but still got nothing. I am sure that something I am doing/haven't done is so simple but I have just totally missed it. Please help.

```
ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    // User's info container (Parent iof imageView)
let userInfoContainer: UIView = {
    let head = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    head.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    head.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    head.layer.borderWidth = 1
    print(head.isUserInteractionEnabled) // Returns true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
    head.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    return head
}()
// Users name
let userName: UITextField = {
    let name = UITextField()
    name.text = "John Doe"
    name.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    name.isUserInteractionEnabled  = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
    name.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    return name
}()

    // User's profile image
let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "avatar"))
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped)))
    return imageView
}()
//
//
// skipping other UI elements
//
//
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Authentication bits

    self.title = "Profile View"
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.view.addSubview(userInfoContainer)
    self.view.addSubview(profileImageView)
    self.view.addSubview(userName)
    } // end viewDidLoad
func tapped() {
    print(123)
}

// setup constraints
func setupUserInfoContainer() {
    userInfoContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    userInfoContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    userInfoContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
}
// profile image arrangement
func setupProfileImage() {
    profileImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userInfoContainer.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userInfoContainer.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

}

func setupLabels() {
    userName.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    userName.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    userName.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    userName.isEnabled = false
}
} // end view controller
```

Rendered View:
[image: ProfileViewController]
View Hierarchy
[image: ViewHeiarchy]
Extra information that is *likely* not necessary: ProfileViewController is being handled by a UITabBarController but from what I have seen, that shouldn't make a difference.

**Update**
From looking around it looks like the appropriate swift 3 syntax is 
`let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapped(_:)))` but I think having that line in the closure is what's causing this error to be thrown `../ProfileViewController.swift:37:74: Value of type '(NSObject) -> () -> ProfileViewController' has no member 'tapped'`

If someone could explain how I can fix this that would be stellar.

Comment: Can you try changing the signature of tapped to tapped(_ sender: Any) and change it in the selectors to tapped(_:) ?

Comment: I changed the signature, but still got the error, listed above. @ConnorG

Comment: Check if the user interaction is enabled of viewcontoller's view

Comment: Or check with view debugger, maybe somthing with clear background is on that views

Comment: `self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled` returns true @Tiko

Comment: @Tiko doesn't look like there is anything obstructing the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can assign a gesture recognizer in this manner...

```
1 let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
2     let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "avatar"))
3     imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
4     imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
5     imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
6     imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
7     imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped)))
8     return imageView
9 }()
```

On line 7, what is `self`? It is the *function* that is returning a `UIImageView`.

Your `func tapped()` is not part of that function... it belongs to `ProfileViewController`.

You *might* be able to find a way to change the target, but a couple minutes of trying different approaches has not yielded any luck for me.

I think you need to create and add the GestureRecognizer(s) inside `ProfileViewController / viewDidLoad()` (or elsewhere within that class).

Comment: Ahhh, so self in the context I have it in references the UIImageView not ProfileViewController. Pulling that line into viewDidLoad changes the reference to to the view controller. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Yes... ish :) In your context, self is not even the UIImageView... it's the *function* that returns UIImageView. The other part, yep... inside viewDidLoad "self" will refer to the ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you didn't set delegate to the tap gesture. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675209/how-to-call-gesture-tap-on-uiview-programmatically-in-swift)

Hope this will work

Comment: That did not work. Adding `tap.delegate = self` from inside the closure tries to set  `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate? = ProfileViewController`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just initiliaise your image view at the top of the class like

```
 let profileImageView = UIImageView()
```

and create a function to configure the imageview and add it as a subview such in view did load. That should work

```
func configureImageView() { 
    #add methods and customize image view
    #add image view to sub view 
}
```