# how to use addTarget with labels, imageview or uiview?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit, tableview

While using table cells, we implement buttons and associate actions using "addTarget" with the button just like below

```
cell.button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionforbutton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

how we can associate other properties like labels, `UIImageView` or `UIView` of the table cell in a similar fashion to perform certain actions, as I couldn't find " addTarget " while using the labels, `UIImageView` or `UIView`

Comment: You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer` for this

Comment: You can use [`UITapGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer)

Comment: @KishanBhatiya can please provide me with some code example for this as I am new to the swift coding

Comment: @rishi Check this [link](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2017/05/uitapgesturerecognizer-tutorial-in.html)

Comment: @iOSDev the link you shared is for objective c, i am working with swift

Comment: @rishi check:  https://medium.com/app-makers/how-to-add-a-tap-gesture-to-uilabel-in-xcode-swift-7ada58f1664

Comment: @rishi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675209/how-to-call-gesture-tap-on-uiview-programmatically-in-swift check this

Comment: @rishi also you can convert objective c to swift with https://objectivec2swift.com, if you need.

Comment: Are the labels, UIImageView or UIView in cell or in the viewController?

Comment: @PGDev labels, UIImageView or UIView are in the cell

Comment: @rishi I updated the link https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2017/05/uitapgesturerecognizer-tutorial-in.html

Comment: @rishi Added an answer explaining the approach you can opt.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use UITapGestureRecognizer

Here is the Sample Code:

```
  let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(actionforView(_:)))
  VIEW.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
  VIEW.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer` on `UILabel`, `UIImageView` etc.

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblStatus: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
    lblStatus.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    lblStatus.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)


}

@objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let a = (sender.view as? UILabel)?.text else { return }
    print(a)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` in `tableview or collectionview cell` then only add `target` in the `cellForItemAt or cellForRowAt`. Allocation and initialization should be placed in `awakeFromNib` of the custom class of the cell! If you create `UITapGestureRecognizer` in `cellForRowAt` then it will initialize every time when `cellForRowAt` getting called and it is not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain the approach using a `customView` of type `UIView`.

In your `TableViewCell's` `awakeFromNib()` method, add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `customView` with `target` as `self` and `selector` as the relevant method to be called when the `customView` is tapped, `customViewTapped(_:)` in the below code.

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var customView: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(customViewTapped(_:)))
        self.customView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    @objc func customViewTapped(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("customView Tapped")
    }
}
```

Same thing you can do for `UILabel`, `UIImageView` and other view elements.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do actually, there are two common practice to have control on ViewCels, since those are views you can simply create and extensions to make your work time less. For example;

```
//This enum can be extended due to demand
enum GestureRecognizerType {
    case Tap
    case Pinch
    case Rotate
}

extension UIView {
func addRecognizer(_ gType:GestureRecognizerType, handleGesture:Selector, _ controller:UIViewController){
    var recognizer:UIGestureRecognizer!
    switch gType {
    case .Pinch:
        recognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: controller, action: handleGesture)
    case .Rotate:
          recognizer = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: controller, action: handleGesture)
    case .Tap:
          recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: controller, action: handleGesture)
    }
    self.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}
```

Then call wherever you want to. Usage could be like:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad
    let view = UIView()
    view.addRecognizer(.Tap, handleGesture: #selector(handleTap(_:)), self)

}
@objc func handleTap(_ recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    //Handle when the view tapped
}
```

The other practice could be handle all inside of your custom cell Class and give them recognisers when they are set using didSet.