# Programmatically discover identity of first responder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I want a UITextField to be sent the resignFirstResponder message if it is being edited and a user touches elsewhere on the screen. Since there are several text fields I need a way to programmatically determine which one is the first responder to send it the message. How can I do this? Is there some sort of global first responder object?

Thanks,
Jacob

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/how-do-i-legally-get-the-current-first-responder-on-the-screen-on-an-iphone

Comment: That looks like a promising answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to [find the first responder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/how-do-i-legally-get-the-current-first-responder-on-the-screen-on-an-iphone) and tell it to `resignFirstResponder`.

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` inherits from `UIResponder` so you can use `isFirstResponder` (which returns a `BOOL`) to query it.

```
if ([myTextField isFirstResponder]) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Let's say a user is editing a UITextField in a UITableViewCell and he taps the background in another UITableViewCell. That UITableViewCell has no access to its sibling UITableViewCells, so I would have to pass a message up to a parent view to pass another message back down to all the cells. Is this what you recommend?