# How to get change text from textfield

Tags: iphone, sdk

I have tableview with custom cells.The cell is having 2 textfields.From viewcontroller i need to find the changed text in that textfield.

if i use

```
* (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

this method is not at calling calling from the mainviewcontroller.

So i am sending notification like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(CalculateAmountInCartList:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

here i am getting that textfiled text is changed.But i dont have control on that which text field and index of the particular cell also i am not getting.

Please give any suggestions.

Thanks,
Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using tag, not sure this is best way..

add tag to textfield in viewDidLoad method..

textField.tag = 1; //Integer number .. 1,10, 99, etc.

in
(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
   if (textField.tag == 1) {
   }
   if (textField.tag == 2){
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to post a message using NSNotificationCenter you know.

```
- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

So you could stick pretty much anything you want in a NSDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you try and determine which field is the first responder; there is example code here [Get the current first responder without using a private API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/how-do-i-legally-get-the-current-first-responder-on-the-screen-on-an-iphone) explaining how to do that.

then I would also associate a tag to each of the edit fields so you know what row in the table was associated with the edit field, similar to what @KiranThorat suggested