# Walking the responder chain to pass custom events. Is this wrong?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, events

According to the iOS documentation, the responder chain is used to pass touch events "up the chain". It's also used for actions generated by controls. Fine.

What I really would like to do is send a **custom** event "up the chain". The first responder to pick up on the event will handle it. This seems like a pretty common pattern, but I can't find any good explanation on how to do it the "iOS/Cocoa way".

Since the responder chain is exactly what I need, I came up with a solution like this:

```
// some event happened in my view that 
// I want to turn into a custom event and pass it "up":

UIResponder *responder = [self nextResponder];

while (responder) {

   if ([responder conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ItemSelectedDelegate)]) {
       [responder itemSelected:someItem];
       break;
   } 

   responder = [responder nextResponder];
}
```

This works perfectly, but I have a feeling that there should be other ways of handling this. Walking the chain manually this way doesn't seem very... nice.

Note that notifications are not a good solution here, because I only want the objects in the view hierarchy to be involved, and notifications are global.

What's the best way of handling this in iOS (and Cocoa for that matter)?

**EDIT**:

***What do I want to accomplish?***

I have a view controller, which has a view, which has subviews etc... Several of the subviews are of a specific type that show an item from the database. When the user taps this view, a signal should be sent to the controller to navigate to a detail page of this item.

The view that handles the tap is several levels below the main view in the view hierarchy. I have to tell the controller (or in some cases a specific subview "up the chain") that an item was selected.

Listening to notifications would be an option, but I don't like that solution because selecting an item is not a global event. It's strictly tied to the current view controller.

Comment: "...I have a feeling that there should be other ways of handling this..." There may be, but it's hard to tell without knowing exactly why you want to pass a custom event up the chain. What's your end goal?

Comment: See my added explanation in the question.

Comment: Re this five year old question ... here's the beautiful modern Swift way to do certain tasks like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37515358/294884

Comment: And even better ... https://blog.veloxdb.com/2016/05/12/bubbling-events-using-uiresponder-in-swift/

Comment: Using showDetailViewController is the correct way to accomplish this which makes use of canPerformAction and targetViewControllerForAction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're pretty close. What would be more standard is something like this:

```
@implementation NSResponder (MyViewController)
- (void)itemSelected:(id)someItem
{
    [[self nextResponder] itemSelected:someItem];
}
@end
```

That's generally how events get passed up the chain by default. Then in the right controller, override that method to instead take a custom action.

This may not be the right pattern for what you want to achieve, but it is a good way to pass messages up the responder chain.

Comment: That's pretty awesome. Makes perfect sense, and it would certainly help to solve my problem. Is this pattern described anywhere?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Also I realise I answered in terms of Cocoa, but it should all be as applicable to Cocoa Touch.

Comment: Why isn't this pattern documented anywhere?

Comment: Beautifully Bubbling events in Swift ... https://blog.veloxdb.com/2016/05/12/bubbling-events-using-uiresponder-in-swift/

Answer (score 16):

[UIApplication has a method for just this purpose](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/sendAction:to:from:forEvent:), as does [its Cocoa cousin](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/sendAction:to:from:). You can replace all of that code in your question with one message.

Comment: I have read this, and somehow I didn't notice the line in the documentation that says *"If target is nil, the application sends the message to the first responder, from whence it progresses up the responder chain until it is handled."*. Thanks a lot for this answer! Very helpful!

Comment: Followup question: This seems to be a great solution, but it assumes you're always working with UIEvent objects. UIEvent objects are very limited in scope (only touches, gestures, etc...). What if I want a higher-level custom event like "item x selected", or "item x deleted"? That wouldn't work with "sendAction"

Comment: while you could indeed replace all the code with 1 message, you lose the ability to send some data or parameter along? As sendAction:to:from:forEvent: does not support this, unless you would misuse the from or event parameter. You could grab the data from the from parameter yourself, but I'd like the data or context to be bundled and independent.

Comment: Misusing the from: parameter there isn't very practical, because it is being assumed to be a UIControl subclass.

Comment: Rather than linking to the overall docs, could you please provide a specific answer to the question. Which is the method you recommend?

Comment: @richarddas: I've tweaked the links. They are both addressed to the specific methods in question, although (due to a frustrating implementation detail in the previous generation of Apple's documentation framing gizmo) you would have to look at the URL for the Cocoa one at the moment. I'll save you the effort: The Cocoa link goes to `sendAction:to:from:`.

Comment: Aha, cool thanks! I've implemented `sendAction:to:from` in my app and it's working great. But yeah, walking the Responder Chain can very easily lead to code that's hard to manage, since you can only pass params via the `from:` object, which is hacky.

Answer (score 5):

Peter's solution works if you are sure that the *first responder* is set correctly. If you want more control over which object is notified about events, you should use [targetForAction:withSender:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/targetForAction:withSender:) instead.

This allows you to specify the first view that should be able to handle the event, and from there it will crawl up the responder chain until it finds an object that can handle the message.

Here is a [fully documented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19169271/35690) function you can use:

```
@interface ABCResponderChainHelper
/*!
 Sends an action message identified by selector to a specified target's responder chain.
 @param action 
    A selector identifying an action method. See the remarks for information on the permitted selector forms.
 @param target 
    The object to receive the action message. If @p target cannot invoke the action, it passes the request up the responder chain.
 @param sender
    The object that is sending the action message.
 @param userInfo
    The user info for the action. This parameter may be @c nil.
 @return
    @c YES if a responder object handled the action message, @c NO if no object in the responder chain handled the message.
 @remarks
    This method pushes two parameters when calling the target. This design enables the action selector to be one of the following:
 @code
 - (void)action
 - (void)action:(id)sender
 - (void)action:(id)sender userInfo:(id)userInfo@endcode
*/
+ (BOOL)sendResponderChainAction:(SEL)action to:(UIResponder *)target from:(id)sender withUserInfo:(id)userInfo;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation ABCResponderChainHelper
+ (BOOL)sendResponderChainAction:(SEL)action to:(UIResponder *)target from:(id)sender withUserInfo:(id)userInfo {
    target = [target targetForAction:action withSender:sender];
    if (!target) {
        return NO;
    }

    NSMethodSignature *signature = [target methodSignatureForSelector:action];
    const NSInteger hiddenArgumentCount = 2; // self and _cmd
    NSInteger argumentCount = [signature numberOfArguments] - hiddenArgumentCount;
    switch (argumentCount) {
        case 0:
            SuppressPerformSelectorLeakWarning([target performSelector:action]);
            break;
        case 1:
            SuppressPerformSelectorLeakWarning([target performSelector:action withObject:sender]);
            break;
        case 2:
            SuppressPerformSelectorLeakWarning([target performSelector:action withObject:sender withObject:userInfo]);
            break;
        default:
            NSAssert(NO, @"Invalid number of arguments.");
            break;
    }

    return YES;
}
@end
```

Note: this uses the [SuppressPerformSelectorLeakWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7933931/35690) macro.

This works great in a UITableView. Imagine you have a gesture recognizer on the cell, and you need to inform the view controller of the action that was performed. Instead of having to create a delegate for the cell, and then forwarding the message to the delegate, you can use the responder chain instead.

Sample usage (sender):

```
// in table view cell class:
- (void)longPressGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    // ...
    [ABCResponderChainHelper sendResponderChainAction:@selector(longPressCell:) to:self from:self withUserInfo:nil];
}
```

Here `self` refers to the cell itself. The [responder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Responder.html) [chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html) ensures that the method is first sent to the `UITableViewCell`, then the `UITableView`, and eventually to the `UIViewController`.

Sample usage (receiver):

```
#pragma mark - Custom Table View Cell Responder Chain Messages
- (void)longPressCell:(UITableViewCell *)sender {
    // handle the long press
}
```

If you tried to do the same thing with [sendAction:to:from:forEvent:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/sendAction:to:from:forEvent:), you have two problems:

- In order for it to work with the responder chain, you must pass in `nil` to the `to` parameter, at which point it will start the messaging at the *first responder* rather than an object of your choice. Controlling the *first responder* can be cumbersome. With this method, you simply tell it at which object to start.
- You can't easily pass a second argument with arbitrary data. You [would need to subclass `UIEvent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24639472/35690) and add a property such as `userInfo` and pass that along in the event argument; a clumsy solution in this case.