# PerformSelector warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-warnings, performselector

I'm receiving  a warning

> PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown

**In the code:**

```
- (void) callDelegate: (SEL) selector withArg: (id) arg error: (NSError*) err
{
    assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
    if([delegate respondsToSelector: selector])
    {
        if(arg != NULL)
        {
            //this line the warning
            [delegate performSelector: selector 
                           withObject: arg 
                           withObject: err]; 
        }
        else
        {
            //this line the warning
            [delegate performSelector: selector 
                           withObject: err]; 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Missed Method");
    }
}
```

**Header:**

```
@interface Topscore : UIViewController <NSObject> {

//
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [performSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown)

Comment: I think this [good post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown) explain the problem very well !May it be helpful !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a warning generated by the compiler because -Wundeclared-selector was used while compiling and automatic reference counting (ARC) is enabled. This can be, in general, safely ignored, as it's obvious that the selector in the variable named "selector" is unknown at compile time, as it will have its value assigned at runtime.

Comment: Thanks but in my app it's returning the NSLOG; Missed Method. This is wrong

Comment: That means the object does not implement that method (thus does not respond to the specified selector). It does NOT cause a memory leak then, because if the "else" branch of the if structure is reached, the -[delegeta performSelector] method hasn't been invoked, thus it couldn't retain the object, so no memory leaks.

Comment: Did you remember putting a colon behind the selector for each argument? The selector for `-(void)methodWithObject:(id)arg1;` actually is `@selector(methodWithObject:)`. The colon is part of it.

Comment: "This can be, in general, safely ignored..." unless the selector happens to begin with `new`, `alloc`, `retain`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`

Answer (score 43):

Your `if ... respondsToSelector: selector` won't work because your `selector` is just the name of the method. For your case you need to check

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(method::)]
```

and for the other case just for `method:`.

Anyway, you can supress the warning like this:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
    [self performSelector:nextView];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Selectively ignoring the warning is super handy. Thanks.

Comment: I figured out that it is enough to use `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"` at the beginning of the class implementation.

Comment: @Julian but then you don't know if there is a real issue somewhere else in your class implementation. On the other hand you can disable the warning globally in your build settings if you don't mind...

Answer (score 3):

You can also use objc_msgSend instead of performSelector, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043999/im-writing-a-button-class-in-objective-c-with-arc-how-do-i-prevent-clangs-m).

Comment: Why overkill? It's just another way to do the same thing, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You could add **-Wno-arc-performSelector-leaks** for `WARNING_CFLAGS` in the `Build Settings`.
[image]

[Found the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7954697/1141395)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is adding this macro to your pch File. Or .m file..

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wundeclared-selector"
```