# Why is objc_msgSend causing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: objective-c, selector, exc-bad-access, objc-message-send

I'm making a class, that given an `object` target, a `selector` to watch for, and a `displayTitle` will output a string in this format: `@"displayTitle: object.selector"`. It then registers itself through KVO so that anytime the `value` of `object.selector` changes, it can notify a view controller to update the view. I am using this as an abstract and reusable way to show a description of various properties of an object to a user.

When I try to get the value of `object.selector`, I can't do `[object performSelector:selector]` because [LLVM gives errors when you use performSelector with a dynamic selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043999/im-writing-a-button-class-in-objective-c-with-arc-how-do-i-prevent-clangs-m). 
So, I did exactly what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7073899/2564682) suggested: I used `objc_msgSend(object, selector)`.

```
- (instancetype)initWithSelector:(SEL)selector onObject:(NSObject*)object displayTitle:(NSString*)displayTitle {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        id value;

        if ([object respondsToSelector:selector) {
            // Used objc_msgSend instead of performSelector to suppress a LLVM warning which was caused by using a dynamic selector.
            value = objc_msgSend(object, selector);
        } else {
            return nil;
        }

        [self setItemDescription:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", displayTitle, value]];
    }

    return self;
}
```

And I got an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`!

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see in the screenshot, I made sure that 
doing `[object selector]` works.

What is going on, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You assign the result of your `objc_msgSend` call to a variable of type `id` so ARC kicks in and tries to retain the resulting object (crash is in `objc_retain` as you can see in the stack to the left). However, the result isn’t an object but an integer of value 8, which `objc_retain` takes to be a pointer. But there are no valid pointers this low, so you get the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Just change the type of `value` to be `NSUInteger` (or any other non-object type). But make sure all potential `selector`s return data of the same type. Alternatively, make sure to always return an object (or `nil`), which can be retained by ARC.

Comment: Is there a way to make it so ARC can determine if `value` is an object or not, so that my class can handle objects *and* non objects? I know I could make the property be a `NSNumber`, as @VincentGeurci said, but that would be rather inconvenient as I need to use the value frequently in other places in the application.

Comment: The only solution in objective-c to hold object and non objects... is to hold objects :D i.e NSNumbers. Note that in recent llvm versions you can do `NSNumber *x = @(5)`, look for literals. For more, wait for Swift which kinda solves this :)

Comment: You could also introspect value to determine its objective-C type to automatically encode/decode it. But that's non trivial (low level objc_xxx methods), NSNumber way much much easier.

Comment: @EthenA.Wilson You could use `[[object methodSignatureForSelector:selector] methodReturnType]` to determine the return type. However, this return type is implementation-specific so it would be best to call this for a selector whose result you know for comparison. On my machine, selectors that return objects have a return type of `'@'`.

Comment: "Just change the type of value to be NSUInteger" I think that will make it not compile, as `obj_msgSend` is declared with `id` as return type.

Comment: @newacct Yes, you’re right, there’s more to do than “just” changing the type, there’s a cast and possibly some ARC compiler directive involved.

Answer (score 4):

Just like with calling a function in C, in order to call a method in Objective-C, you need to know the exact type signature of the method.

When you use `objc_msgSend` and related functions, you need to cast it to the correct function pointer type before calling it. From the other answers and comments, it appears that your method takes no parameters and has return type `NSInteger`. In that case, in order to use it, you must do something like:

```
NSInteger value;
NSInteger (*f)(id, SEL) = (NSInteger (*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend;
value = f(object, selector);
```

Comment: Reference is here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6150 and here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that your value is 8, an Integer?

Thanks to arc, value is attempted to be retained, i.e. retain at adress 0x8, which would explain that `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, 0x8 being a protected address.

If that is your problem, just wrap your value as a `NSNumber`