# objective-c: double pointers to property not allowed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to create a method like this:

```
- (void) checkAndUpdateStringProperty: (NSString **) property{
   if (...) 
      *property = @"whatever";
}
```

I want to use this to pass in a property for the same class:

```
- (void) somewhereElse{
       ....
       [self checkAndUpdateStringProperty: &self.productName];
}
```

But this gives a syntax error, saying "Address of property expression requested". Any reason why? If I replace the class property with a local variable, it works fine:

```
- (void) somewhereElse{
       NSString *name = nil;
       [self checkAndUpdateStringProperty: &name];
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Properties should only ever be accessed through their getter and setter methods, with the exception of initializing and deinitializing them in the object's `init` and `dealloc` methods (when the object is not in a fully consistent state) -- accessing them any other way defeats their purpose and does not respect their attributes (`retain`, `copy`, etc.).

The reason why it doesn't compile is because property accessors are syntactic sugar for method calls, and you can't take the address of the return value of a method. `self.productName` is identical to `[self productName]`, and `&[self productName]` makes no sense.

If you really want to do this, don't do it with a property, do it with just a regular variable (such as a local variable or ivar), and *document the semantics* of your function: does the calling function need to `release` the returned object?  Etc.  For example, the various Apple methods which take an `NSError**` specify that the error object which is returned, if any, is an autoreleased object, so you should not `release` it yourself unless you also `retain` it.

Comment: The exception to accessing property ivars directly is in `init` and `dealloc` where the class is not in a fully complete form and any side effects could be a problem.

Comment: Thanks. Actually figured out that (since this was a NSManagedObject) I could pass in the property's name and access the value using valueForKey, and set it inside the 'check' method using setValue:forKey: Didn't need to do the double-pointer indirection.

Answer (score 7):

There are very few places in the Apple APIs that a value is passed in this fashion, the main one being `NSError`.  It is really best to just return the result.  If you do have a reference parameter the general Apple rule is that it should be the last parameter that that the method name begin with "`get`" as in `getCheckAndUpdateStringProperty`.

But you can do it, it is just not what we are used to.

The error you are seeing is that `self.productName` is really shorthand for the method call: `[self productName]` so  `&self.productName` is interpreted as `&[self productName]`.

Further in this case if productName is a @property with a retain attribute the reference counting will be subverted.

Answer (score 5):

If you are really careful about the ownership attributes, you can get around this issue by staring at the following:

```
[self property]
```

vs:

```
self.property
```

vs:

```
self->property
```

Once you are clear about the difference you can try this:

```
[self checkAndUpdateStringProperty: &self->productName]
```

Note the use of: **->**

I use this all the time when the property attribute is *assign* and when it is a primitive, non object type: (float, int, ...)

Comment: `self->productName` is a really bad idea, it breaks encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

create a property of that variable,which you want to access in another class (@property(strong,nonatomic) ;) and then synthesise it....
(@synthesize ;) and then access via object name of that class,where you define property and synthesise it.....

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this using the selectors instead (you'll have to convert it to a c function to get it to work without warning (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20058585/1283385)):

```
- (void) checkAndUpdateStringProperty: (SEL)setter {
   if (...) 
     IMP imp = [self methodForSelector:setter];
     void (*func)(id, SEL, id) = (void *)imp;
     func(self, setter, @"whatever");
}
```

Use this to pass in the selector for the same class:

```
- (void) somewhereElse{
       ....
       [self checkAndUpdateStringProperty:@selector(setProductName:)];
}
```