# How to declare selector as a property iOS and how to use my property next?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, uicontrol

I write next. All code wrote with ARC

```
@interface MPEvent : UIImageView
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) SEL action;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id target;

@end
```

Is selector declared in correct way?

In implementation I use my properties next this way:

```
- (void)sendActionToTargetFromView:(id)view {
    [target performSelector:action withObject:view];
}
```

But compiler show me a warning
warning: Semantic Issue: PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown

How to fix this warning?

Comment: Possible answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the below example -Warc-performSelector-leaks is ignored for only a single line of code, after which the diagnostics return to whatever state had previously existed.

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
    [self.ticketTarget performSelector: self.ticketAction withObject: self];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

[pragma warnings help](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#diagnostics_pragmas)
[Detailed description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown)