# Crash when using performSelector: with a SEL passed from another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, selector, performselector

Is it possible to send a selector to another class and have it perform on that other class?

This seems to crash with the error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[webManager _selector]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. If this is not possible, what would you recommend as an alternative?

The methods are placed in the order that they are performed.

```
//in HomeViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    WebManager *webManager = [[WebManager alloc] init];
    URLCreator *urlCreator = [[URLCreator alloc] initWithParam:@"default"];
    [webManager load:[urlCreator createURL] withSelector:@selector(testSelector)];
}
//in WebManager, which is also the delegate for the URL it loads when the load method is called...
-(void)load:(NSString*)url withSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    _selector = selector;    
    [self load:url];
}

-(void)load:(NSString*)url{
    NSURLRequest * request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}

//now the delegate response, ALSO in WebManager
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"Connection did finish loading. Parsing the JSON");

    [self getJSONDict:rawData]; //parses the data to a dictionary

    //perform the selector that is requested if there is one included
    if (_selector)
    {
        NSLog(@"Performing selector: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_selector));
        //the selector is called testSelector
        [self performSelector:@selector(_selector)];    
    }
}

- (void)testSelector //also in the WebManager class
{
    NSLog(@"Selector worked!");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(_selector)];
```

A `SEL` is a type representing the name of a method. `@selector` is a compiler directive which converts the *literal text* inside the brackets into a `SEL`.

But `_selector`, your ivar, *already contains* a `SEL`. You're converting the *text* "_selector" into a `SEL`, and then trying to use that. Since no method with the selector "_selector" exists in the target class, you get an exception.

Change the line to:

```
[self performSelector:_selector];
```

and everything should be dandy. This uses the `SEL` which you already have stored in the *variable* `_selector`.

<sub>Also, generally speaking, please *post your real code* initially.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting a warning stating "PerformSelector may cause a leak." Is there a way to remove this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown

Comment: For future reference for others...

        `#pragma clang diagnostic push
        #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
        [self performSelector:_selector];
        #pragma clang diagnostic pop`

Answer (score 3):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(_selector)];
```

The code above actually translates to [self _selector] which I'm assuming is not what you want. You should change your code to

```
[self performSelector:_selector];
```