# Apple Demo don't have "performSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown" Warning. Anyone know why?

Tags: ios

I'm getting the following warning by the ARC compiler:

> "performSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown".

Here's what I'm doing:

```
[_controller performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"someMethod")];
```

But under [Apple Demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/Cocoa_Autolayout_Demos/Listings/SplitView_ColoredView_m.html), they don't have this Warning for the same code. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

That sample is not an ARC project. The warning you cite is the default with ARC projects.

Comment: Does this mean that I cannot do dynamic selector in ARC environment without compiler warning? Or there is a different way to do this?

Comment: you can. however, the responsibility is all yours to verify that the reference counting is always correct.

Comment: Hi @rayzhang here's a bit more about this warning - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown