# How to dismiss Popover shown on QLPreviewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

How to Dismiss Popover shown on `QLPreviewController`. That popover holds print option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like we don't have control over this popover. I have done work around this by simulating touch event to dismiss the popover.

[Ref this to simulate touch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496761/how-to-fire-uibarbuttonitem-click-event-programmatically)