# How to fire the action of a uibarbuttonitem programatically?

Tags: ios, action, uibarbuttonitem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fire uibarbuttonitem click event programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496761/how-to-fire-uibarbuttonitem-click-event-programmatically)

I have created an `uibarbuttonitem` dynamically and it works properly. I want to fire that `uibarbutton` item action(click) programatically for unit testing.

Even though the code work properly when I log the action of the bar button item  in the application code (not on testing code) it gives null. The code I have used is given below.

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromSelector(barButton.action));
```

In the testing code I have created a bar button called logout and assign barbutton to that.To click the bar button item programatically I followed the following code.

```
[logout.target performSelector:logout.action];
```

But it didn't work . I logged the action of logout button and it also gives null.

```
NSLog(@"%@",logout.action);
```

I want to know how to programatically click a `uibarbuttonitem` which created dynamically .

Comment: rishi,I refered that post .From that I got the code  [logout.target performSelector:logout.action];.But it didn't work

Comment: Show the UIBarbuttonItem declaration, please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code worked with me

```
//in viewDidLoad
item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(logout)];    
toolBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:item];

//In viewWillAppear
[item.target performSelector:item.action];

- (void) logout
{
    NSLog(@"Called");
}
```

I dont know what you mean by click, but the above works

Comment: i am doing this for unit testing. i am writing unit testing for someone else's code. so i cant change it. when i log the action of the button it gives null. so performselector doesnt work. when i ran the application (the one i am testing) it works fine. please be kind enough to give this some thought.

Comment: what does it give you null, did you try the code i posted above?

Comment: yes i did. the action of the button is null. so a selector is not set properly for the button? unfortunately i cant find out in the code(the one i am testing) where it is set.

Comment: then maybe it is not set, or even its set later after you do your unit test

Comment: is this the only way to make a uibarbuttonitem do what it does. (setting a selector as its action)? could the selector be null and button still does what it does?

Comment: Nope it should have an action