# UIBarButtonItem action doesn't trigger on tap

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on the signup view controller for an iOS application. I have a `UITextField` for users to enter their gender, with a `UIPickerView` as the `inputView`.

Currently, I'm trying to add a `UIToolbar` as an `inputAccessoryView`. The `UIToolbar` is working fine, but I'm having trouble adding a "Next" button. The button shows properly on the screen, but fails to perform the specified action when tapped.

```
@IBOutlet var genderTextField: UITextField!
var genderPicker:UIPickerView = UIPickerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set up the genderPicker
    genderPicker.delegate = self
    genderPicker.dataSource = self

    // set up the genderToolbar
    var genderToolbar = UIToolbar()
    var genderDoneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "doneWithGender:")
    genderToolbar.items = [genderDoneButton]

    // set inputView and inputAccessoryView for genderTextField
    genderTextField.inputView = genderPicker
    genderTextField.inputAccessoryView = genderToolbar
}

func doneWithGender(sender:AnyObject){
    println("gender button tapped")
}
```

I have followed the advice here: [How to set the action for a UIBarButtonItem in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641350/how-to-set-the-action-for-a-uibarbuttonitem-in-swift) and here: [How to fire the action of a uibarbuttonitem programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241468/how-to-fire-the-action-of-a-uibarbuttonitem-programatically)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might try changing action to "doneWithGender" without the colon, and removing "sender:AnyObject" from the parameter list.

Comment: Thanks -- Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: How about - action: Selector("doneWithGender")

Comment: Nope. Everything seems fine -- except nothing happens.

Comment: I suggest that because I am using @selector syntax in ObjC when creating a UIBarButtonItem to add to a UIToolbar that is set as an inputAccessoryView.

Comment: Selector("doneWithGender") didn't work either.

Comment: Thanks @MikeTaverne -- I believe you just use strings for selectors in Swift https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your toolbar frame is (0,0,0,0) so your button is shown but doesn't respond to user interactions.

Try something like this:

```
var genderToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 44))
```