# How to execute UIBarButtonItem's action in Swift?

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem

How can I execute an UIBarButtonItem's action in Swift ? I need this to write tests.

I've found [an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9496846/1160770) for Objective-C, using the performSelector method, but unfortunately it's not available from Swift.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by adding action to your UIBarButtonItem, you can also change the target.

Example :

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let mySelector: Selector = "showActionAlert"

    let rightNavigationBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: self, action: mySelector)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightNavigationBarItem
}

func showActionAlert() {
    let alertView = UIAlertView(title: "MY ALERT", message: "barButtonItem Tapped", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alertView.show()

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.action = "showSecondAlert"
}

func showSecondAlert() {
    let alertView = UIAlertView(title: "MY ALERT", message: "My second alert", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alertView.show()
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sendAction`-method from `sharedApplication`.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    .sendAction(yourButton.action, to: yourButton.target,
                from: self, forEvent: nil)
```