# why warning with my performSelector

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, performselector

Below is a simple PerformSelector that sends a message to obj to perform the looping method. All works well but I get the following yellow warning.

> PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown.

```
#import "MyClass.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc]init];

        SEL mySel = @selector(looping);
        [obj performSelector:mySel];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This warning does not make sense because the performSelector must be aware of mySel because the looping method does get called  - any ideas whats going on ??

---

**Update**

**MyClass.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject

-(void)looping;

@end
```

**MyClass.m**

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

-(void)looping{

    NSLog(@"Hey, i'm looping");

}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update -- The Real Answer**

This is ARC specific:

[performSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown)

In short, ARC uses information based on the naming conventions and any additional attributes bound to the selector. When accessing a selector by name and performing it via the `performSelector:` family of methods, that information is lost and the compiler is warning you that it must make some assumptions regarding reference counting because this information is stripped away.

In short, the specific program you posted is safe *but* you are encouraged to use an alternative which is ARC-friendly.

**The Previous Response**

A selector's declaration does not need to be visible to the current translation in order to call it.

The compiler is allowed to assume default types for parameters and return types for class and instance methods (`id` is the default).

There are several compiler warnings which can warn you of these shady actions.

You probably forgot to declare the selector `looping` in the `@interface`, or you may have omitted the colon, if it has arguments: `looping:` would be its name.

Comment: Thanks for you help but as a newb Im still bit confused.If possible could you explain or even better send an example of what you mean by not declaring the current translation. The looping method is in the interface and does not require a colon because it does not take in any arguments (it simply logs out a string).

Comment: @pete thanks for expanding your post. i've updated it with a real answer.

Comment: that explains it and yes I have got ARC switched on. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this warning is due to that u have not told the compiler where the selector resides, import the file where it is or add the selector to header file where it should be

Comment: the selector is a class method from MyClass. I have placed #import "MyClass.h" at the top of main -

Comment: do u have declared that in ur MyClass.h?

Comment: compiler only knows the things that are predeclared to a line or included through some library

Comment: yes the method is declared in the header file - I have just made an edit to show all files

Comment: ok do this then
if([obj respondsToselecto:mySel]){[obj performSelector:mySel];}

Comment: I had to change your you code to: if([obj respondsToSelector:mySel]) { [obj performSelector:mySel];};  But all this does is call the method again. As stated - the selector works but I get a warning