# Execute selector to find UIImageView using concatenated NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, selector

I'm new to Objective-C so sorry if this is a newbie question.
I've searched for a couple of hours and can't seem to find an answer to my question.

So I'm trying to access a UIImageView so I can hide/unhide it by concatenating strings together to get the name of the UIImageView which should hide/unhide.

I have it working by doing:

```
self.faceItemEyesFrightened.hidden = false;
```

However the **Frightened** part of the name could be different each time a button is clicked so, trying to refactor my code I run a function which returns the type of UIImageView should be affected.

So I have the following:

```
NSString *fullEmotionString = [@"faceItemEyes" stringByAppendingString:emotionIs];
```

where **emotionIs** would be **Frightened**, therefore forming

```
faceItemEyesFrightened
```

So my problem comes when I wish to do something like this:

```
self.fullEmotionString.hidden = false;
```

Obviously that's not the right way of doing it but I'm not sure how it should be done, any advice greatly appreciated.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `NSSelectorFromString` like this:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(fullEmotionString);
UIImageView *imageView = [self performSelector:selector];
imageView.hidden = NO;
```

Note, that this requires a getter called `faceItemEyesFrightened` to be defined, which is usually this case if you're using properties and didn't change the name of the accessors.

That being said, I think this is not an optimal solution to your problem.
You could for instance subclass `UIImageView` and add an `enum MyImageViewEmotion` that describes the emotion in the image. Then, instead of using lots of variables, like `faceItemEyesFrightened` or `faceItemEyesHappy`, you could put all of them in a simple array and then get one of them like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.emotion == %ld",
                            MyImageViewEmotionFrightened];
MyImageView *imageView = [eyeImageViews filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate][0]
```

Of use an `NSDictionary`, where you put the emotion string as the key and the image views as the value. Then you could access them very easily:

```
UIImageView *imageView = emotionViewDictionary[@"Frightened"];
```

By the way, boolean values in Objective-C are called `YES` and `NO` and not `true` and `false`.

Comment: Perfect :) Thanks for the fast response.  It is coming up with the warning `PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown` however [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793116/to-prevent-warning-from-performselect-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is) deals with this.  Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. I added some alternative suggestions to your problem.