# Memory leaks in using perform selector

Tags: objective-c, memory, memory-leaks, performselector

```
-(void)walkDOM:(SEL)visitor node:(QuadNode*)node {
    [self performSelector:visitor withObject:node]; /* ------>100% leaks shown here */
    NSArray* children = node.children;
    if (children) {
        for (QuadNode* child in children) {
            [self walkDOM:visitor node:child];
        }
    }
}
```

I dont know what's wrong in the above it crashes.Any Help Suggestions!!!!!

**Edit:**

```
-(void)registerFramesetterVisitor:(TDOMNode*)node {
     [strMaker reset]; 
     [node registerFramesetter:self]; 
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown

Comment: You'll need to show us the methods that `visitor` describes.

Comment: -(void)registerFramesetterVisitor:(TDOMNode*)node {
    [strMaker reset];
    [node registerFramesetter:self];
} In the above code my selector is registerFramesetterVisitor

Comment: Where is `[NSObject performSelector:withObject:]` defined? I cannot find it...

Comment: @trojanfoe: It's defined in the NSObject Protocol Reference: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSObject)

Comment: OK thanks - didn't think to look there...

Answer (score 1):

It's only a matter of compiler warnings, you can suppress them using:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
    [self performSelector:visitor withObject:node];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

[Source](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/articles/migrating-your-code-to-objective-c-arc/#performSelector_may_cause_a_leak_because_its_selector_is_unknown)

Comment: Given the OP used the phrase "100% leaks shown here" that would imply that he's seeing these leaks using Instruments; which as you know is way past compilation...

Comment: Another way to see these leaks is using Build & Analyze. In that way the compiler would complain about the performSelector which is something I experienced a few weeks ago.

Comment: But Analyze doesn't use the term "100% leaks..." does it; Instruments does though.