# Objective C >> Is there a way to check a Selector return value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector, return-value

let's say I have a selector that may be assigned to several different methods - each one has a different return value.

Is there a way to check what is the return value of the method the selector is holding before calling "performSelector"?

Comment: Can you give some sample code?

Comment: Do you mean the actual value, or the type? I don't think you can know the return value as it depends on the method execution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a way to check what is the return value of the method the selector is holding before calling "performSelector"?

Value? No. Type? Yap. It seems that you want the **return type** of the method (or your question wouldn't make sense).

```
Method m = class_getInstanceMethod([SomeClass class], @selector(foo:bar:));
char type[128];
method_getReturnType(m, type, sizeof(type));
```

Then you can examine the returned type string in `type`. For example, `"v"` means void (google the full list).

Comment: Make sure to use: #import <objc/runtime.h>

Comment: No need to use runtime functions. You can just get the method signature from the object and selector, and get the return type from there.

Answer (score 7):

you might use NSInvocation which is recommended in Apple Docs for this purpose

here is some sample code for using NSInvocation

```
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"someSelector");
if ([someInstance respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
                                [[someInstance class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector]];
    [invocation setSelector:selector];
    [invocation setTarget:someInstance];
    [invocation invoke];
    float returnValue;
    [invocation getReturnValue:&returnValue];
    NSLog(@"Returned %f", returnValue);
}
```

Comment: `[[someInstance class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector]` should just be `[someInstance methodSignatureForSelector:selector]`

Comment: Keep in mind to separate instance method and class method

Answer (score 1):

#### If the method doesn’t return an object (it returns a primitive type), then use NSInvocation instead.

```
@implementation NSObject(SafePerformSelector)
-(id) performSelectorSafely:(SEL)aSelector;
{
    NSParameterAssert(aSelector != NULL);
    NSParameterAssert([self respondsToSelector:aSelector]);

    NSMethodSignature* methodSig = [self methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];
    if(methodSig == nil)
        return nil;

    const char* retType = [methodSig methodReturnType];
    if(strcmp(retType, @encode(id)) == 0 || strcmp(retType, @encode(void)) == 0){
        return [self performSelector:aSelector];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"-[%@ performSelector:@selector(%@)] shouldn't be used. The selector doesn't return an object or void", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(aSelector));
        return nil;
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score -1):

performSelector: always returns an `id`. The actual type returned is determined by the method you call; so there is no way to know it beforehand.

Comment: The answers above clearly explain that it IS possible to know it beforehand.