# iOS 7 runtime headers method invoke

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

How to invoke this method and what parameters would be passed?

This method is available in iOS 7 run time headers.

```
- (BOOL)uninstallApplication:(id)arg1 withOptions:(id)arg2
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling this method from [self device] ?

```
if ([[self device] applicationIsInstalled:[self uniqueAppIdentifier] type: nil error: &error]) 
    BOOL uninstalled = [[self device ] uninstallApplication:[self uniqueAppIdentifier] withOptions: nil error: &error];
```

Comment: Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
    NSObject* workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:@selector(defaultWorkspace)];
                                                                                                                      BOOL result=[[workspace performSelector:@selector(uninstallApplication) withObject:@"" withObject:nil] boolValue];

Comment: now that'show I am calling this method but , now it gives me another error  that is -[LSApplicationWorkspace uninstallApplication]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: You called a wrong selector: @selector(uninstallApplication) should be @selector(uninstallApplication:withOptions:)

Comment: yes you are right. Thanks for correction. now I need to send right parameters. Then hopefully it will work fine.

Comment: now I want get the app icons by using this method  (id)iconsDictionary; in LSResourceProxy header. How can I do that ?

Comment: You should ask a new question in a new thread, but here is your answer to get return value from a selector http://stackoverflow.com/a/14602937/2219009
Also please don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if so

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445692/ios-6-runtime-headers-method-to-open-an-application-using-its-bundle-identifier