# iOS 6 Runtime headers method to open an application using its bundle identifier[Non-jailbreak]

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

I want to open an app programmatically through its bundle identifier by using iOS 6 runtime headers method. I have done this in iOS 7 and 8 but I couldn't find any appropriate method in iOS 6. Please guide me how can I do that. Please remember that I am implementing this functionality for enterprise apps.

Working Code in iOS 7 and 8

```
if ([self checkOSVersion] >= 7)
{       
    Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
    NSObject* workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:@selector(defaultWorkspace)];

    BOOL result = [[workspace performSelector:@selector(openApplicationWithBundleID:) withObject:appIdentifier] boolValue];        
}
```

Comment: @Thibaud David  any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to do this without using URL Scheme

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:[NSURL urlWithString:@"yourUrlScheme://"]];
```

Cons : You need to register it in advance, or to know the URL Scheme registered by an app

You can find a list of some URL Scheme [here](http://handleopenurl.com/scheme) or [here](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes)
For other apps, you'll have to extract the .ipa. Here is a way to do it (from [that SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25089026/2219009)) :

> So I went to iTunes on my mac and looked in my App Library for the "APP IN QUESTION".
>
> I then: • Right-Clicked on the "APP IN QUESTION" app and selected “Show in Finder”
>
> • then duplicated the "APP IN QUESTION" .ipa file
>
> • Then I renamed the .ipa file to end in .zip instead (saying, yes make it a .zip if necessary)
>
> • Then I unzipped it to a folder
>
> • I opened the Payload Folder
>
> • I right-clicked the “"APP IN QUESTION".app” and selected “Show Package Contents”
>
> • I opened up the “Info.plist” file in a text editor like the free TextWrangler.app
>
> • I searched for “URL” and found the following:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
              <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
              <array>
                   <string>app-in-question</string>
                   <string>sslapp-in-question</string>
              </array>
           </dict>
        </array>
```

> I was then able to successfully go to Safari and type in: app-in-question:// and sslapp-in-question:// and was prompted if I wanted to launch the App in Question.

EDIT:

This should work

```
void* sbServices = dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBo‌​ardServices", RTLD_LAZY);
int (*SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier)(CFStringRef identifier, Boolean suspended) = dlsym(sbServices, "SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier");
int result = SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier((CFStringRef)bundleId, false);
dlclose(sbServices);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I know the URL scheme approach already. As I mentioned its possible with private framework headers and I have done that successfully  but getting an issue in iOS 6.

Comment: Can you edit your question with your working code for iOS >6 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476982/how-to-open-an-app-by-bundle-id-on-ios

Comment: I have added the working code for iOS 7 and 8. Please have a look.

Comment: Look at this, including comments, it's supposed to work on 6.x http://stackoverflow.com/a/11693879/2219009

Comment: @selector(openApplicationWithBundleID:) is available in iOS 7 and 8 runtime headers. its not available in  iOS 6. so that's why I have to find some other way.

Comment: Doesn't this work ?  SBApplication *app = [[objc_getClass("SBApplicationController") sharedInstance] applicationWithDisplayIdentifier:@"your.bundle.id"];
[[objc_getClass("SBUIController") sharedInstance] activateApplicationFromSwitcher: app];

Comment: void* sbServices = dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices", RTLD_LAZY);
int (*SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier)(CFStringRef identifier, Boolean suspended) = dlsym(sbServices, "SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier");
int result = SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier((CFStringRef)bundleId, false);
dlclose(sbServices);

Comment: Mark it as accepted answer, I edited it with working solution (You need a minimum reputation to upvote a comment)

Comment: I have another question ... I am using this runtime header method to delete an app from iOS device programmtically ..........................Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
    NSObject* workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:@selector(defaultWorkspace)];
    
    
    //BOOL result=[[workspace performSelector:@selector(uninstallApplication:withOptions:) withObject:bundleId withObject:@""] boolValue];

Comment: this method is deletes and an app successfully but app crashes after deleting the app . What i found the issue with this ,,, I am not providing the second argument properly. What do you say ?

Comment: here is the Link iOS 7 runtime headers ...https://github.com/MP0w/iOS-Headers/blob/master/iOS7/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices/LSApplicationWorkspace.h

Comment: I am using this method from the header class     -(_Bool)uninstallApplication:(id)arg1 withOptions:(id)arg2;

Comment: in first argument I am sending the bundle identifier and in second argument I am sending empty string .

Comment: LaunchServies: No placeholder bundle to remove for com.example.apple-samplecode.myPaintApp .   this message I get on my console .

Comment: I think you should pass nil as second argument, but anyway, ask this in a new thread

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31956186/how-to-delete-an-ios-app-programatically-using-private-framework-for-non-jailbro