# How to delete an iOS app programatically using private framework for non-jailbroken device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi

I am making an in-house (Enterprise) app. I want to delete other installed apps from the iOS device programmatically. I have successfully retrieved the installed apps' info (e.g. name, bundleId, version, icon etc.) using Apple's private framework methods. Please tell me how can I do that (i.e. delete an app). Thanks.

Comment: I think you will need Super User Access.

Comment: @HarvantS. What is super user access ?

Comment: @Salman superuser access means you need to jailbreak your device and you become super user .

Comment: `SUDO`  Keyword in linux and unix . That mean `Super User DO` . @BadalShah Yes.

Comment: @BadalShah Thanks for explanation . But I don't want to jailbrake my device.

Comment: @HarvantS.  I found one method in  Private Headers .... That is  - (BOOL)uninstallApplication:(id)arg1 withOptions:(id)arg2;    Its in LSApplicationworkspace. It takes two arguments. I passed first argument bundle identifier and second arguement was nil. This method deleted app successfully but after that crash occurred.

Comment: @BadalShah I found one method in Private Headers .... That is - (BOOL)uninstallApplication:(id)arg1 withOptions:(id)arg2; Its in LSApplicationworkspace. It takes two arguments. I passed first argument bundle identifier and second arguement was nil. This method deleted app successfully but after that crash occurred.

Comment: Its working for me without any crash but the method return `NO` sometimes.

Comment: FYI: You can jailbreak your phone, and hide Cydia, if that is okay with you.

Comment: @Thibaud David any suggestions

Comment: Did you ever get a reliable solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution (No jailbreak No crash) but its not working every time. Sometime it failed to uninstall application and return `NO`.

```
NSBundle *b = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework"];
BOOL success = [b load];
if(success)
{
    Class LSApplicationWorkspace = NSClassFromString(@"LSApplicationWorkspace");
    id si = [LSApplicationWorkspace valueForKey:@"defaultWorkspace"];

    SEL selector=NSSelectorFromString(@"uninstallApplication:withOptions:");
    BOOL what=[si performSelector:selector withObject:@"Bundle_ID" withObject:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with a **non Jailbroken device**, even with private APIs.

Comment: @sleepwalkersfx I found one method in Private Headers .... That is - (BOOL)uninstallApplication:(id)arg1 withOptions:(id)arg2; Its in LSApplicationworkspace. It takes two arguments. I passed first argument bundle identifier and second arguement was nil. This method deleted app successfully but after that crash occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an MDM solution, which gives the company quite a lot of power over enrolled devices. Using iOS software, there is no way whatsoever. And I'll just assume that your enterprise won't let jailbroken phones anywhere near it!