# Using a NSString to set a color for a label

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, selector, uicolor

I want to create a method and use a string value "redColor" to set the UIColor for a label. tableColorName is the NSString "redColor" and I tried to apply a selector to create the UIColor and apply it to my textLabel. Thanks

```
-(void) changeLabelColor
{
    SEL labelColor = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:[@"%@", tableColorName]]);

    UIColor *color = [[UIColor class] performSelector:labelColor];
    self.textLabel.textColor = color;
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure! I do get the warning "PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown" but all i know is that the textLabel is still black!

Comment: @user1827141 : check my answer it works fine..tested

Comment: perform it on the UIColor object, not its class

Comment: for `performSelector` warning: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7933931/642626

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this method

```
-(UIColor *)giveColorfromStringColor:(NSString *)colorname
{
    SEL labelColor = NSSelectorFromString(colorname);
    UIColor *color = [UIColor performSelector:labelColor];
    return color;
}
```

Call as

```
[view setBackgroundColor:[self giveColorfromStringColor:@"redColor"]];
```

The method name takes `colorname` as input and gives the corresponding UIColor

Thus in your case  the call will be

```
self.textLabel.textColor = [self giveColorfromStringColor:@"redColor"];
```

Comment: Worked for me. Now I just need to decide how to handle pink.