# Calling a method by using variables in the method name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

I have a situation in objective-c, specifically for iOS app development, that a particular method will execute and return a number, from 01 - 20. Also, I have 20 different methods, name m01, m02, m03, etc.

How can I program my code so that my first method calls another method that corresponds to the returned number from the first method?

Something like this:

```
[self m[NSStringWithFormat=@"%i", myOutputFromMethod1];
```

Can someone please help me get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the name of a selector using `NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"m%i", myOutputFromMethod1])` and then perform it using `[self performSelector:]`.

Comment: Be aware, though, that the method *must* return an objective-c object (i.e. `NSNumber` as opposed to `int`)

Comment: See my updated answer, you just insert what you were trying to create in your question.

Comment: Awesome! A bit off topic, instead of [self method], how can I call a method from another .h/.m file? Would I need to import something?

Comment: Oh, it can also return `void` just to be clear, but if it does return it has to return an object.

Comment: You can use `performSelector:` on *any* valid objective-c object that inherits from `NSObject` (which is virtually everything).

Comment: Awesome! It is working great, but I received a warning: "PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown". Is this something to worry about? Also, will Appel reject apps that have warnings?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7017537/1155387

Answer (score 2):

```
SEL s = NSSelectorFromString([NSString NSStringWithFormat:@"m%i", myOutputFromMethod1]);
[anObject performSelector:s];
```

Answer (score 2):

Using dozens of methods depending upon a returning value is definitely not a good programming practice, (unless you have some very special requirements which I'm not aware of).
You can call the same method but pass a paramter to it. That parameter can be put into a switch statement, then you can write a 'case' for each value of parameter. For example

```
-(void) method_m :(int)mNum
{
    switch(mNum)
    {
        case 0:
            //your code for method 00
            break;
        case 1:
            //your code for method 01
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SEL s = NSSelectorFromString([NSString NSStringWithFormat: @"m%i", myOutputFromMethod1]);

if ([anObject respondsToSelector: s])
{
    [anObject performSelector: s];
}
```