# Which is better way of handling callback in iOS

Tags: ios, callback, nsurlconnection

I have created a custom Network handler for managing all server calls from Application. This internally uses NSURLConnection and callback a function block once data fetch is complete. Current I can set the callback method or a callback CodeBlock. I wanted to understand which one is better and why.

OPTION 1 :

```
BaseNetworkHelper * helper = [[BaseNetworkHelper alloc] initWithURL:@"request/url/as/string" action:@"action/for/request" params:params];
[helper addFinishAction:self sel:@selector(markReadFinished:)];
```

is this way I get ARC warning when I call the callback method once action is complete. like bellow.

```
if (_target) {
        if ([_target respondsToSelector:selector]) {
            [_target performSelector:selector withObject:rdata];
        }
    }
```

OPTION 2:

```
BaseNetworkHelper * helper = [[BaseNetworkHelper alloc] initWithURL:@"request/url/as/string" action:@"action/for/request" params:params];
[helper startDownload:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            // Business logic for response handling / error handling
        }];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block places the completion code in the same context as the code that begins the request, which makes it easier to read and often captures the values -- already initialized -- you'll want on completion.

If you opt for the target/selector approach, [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown), there's a way to work around the warning in llvm >=3.  (see the highly upvoted answer down the page a bit).