# Sprite Kit Calling a random method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, random, sprite-kit

I am currently making a game in sprite kit and i have 8 methods, I have written all the timing code E.T.C so it calls a method every 1 second, but i want it to call a random one of the eight methods, I have been trying to get this working for weeks, any help would be muchly appreciated, Here is my timing code -

```
- (void)updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:(CFTimeInterval)timeSinceLast {

    self.lastSpawnTimeInterval += timeSinceLast;
    if (self.lastSpawnTimeInterval > 5) {
        self.lastSpawnTimeInterval = 0;
        [self shoot1];
    }
}
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
    // Handle time delta.
    // If we drop below 60fps, we still want everything to move the same distance.
    CFTimeInterval timeSinceLast = currentTime - self.lastUpdateTimeInterval;
    self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;
    if (timeSinceLast > 1) { // more than a second since last update
        timeSinceLast = 1.0 / 60.0;
        self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;
    }

    [self updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:timeSinceLast];

}
```

As you can see instead of `[self shoot1]`i want it to randomly call one of the eight methods, Also all the methods are named Shoot1, Shoot2, all the way to Shoot8. Thankyou

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sprite kit, how can i randomly call a method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716328/sprite-kit-how-can-i-randomly-call-a-method)

Comment: Yes it is, I can't remove because it has answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two options...

**Option 1**

Just pick a random number between 1 and 8, and use a `switch` statement:

```
- (void)updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:(CFTimeInterval)timeSinceLast {
    self.lastSpawnTimeInterval += timeSinceLast;
    if (self.lastSpawnTimeInterval > 5) {
        self.lastSpawnTimeInterval = 0;

        int randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(8);
        switch(randomNumber) {
            case 0:
                [self shoot1];
                break;
            case 1:
                [self shoot2];
                break;
            // ... cases 2-6
            case 7:
                [self shoot8];
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

Rewrite your `shootN` methods so that you only have one method that takes an integer as a parameter:

```
- (void)shoot:(int)index;
```

Then, you can just do the following:

```
[self shoot:arc4random_uniform(8)];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also live dangerously...

```
int random = arc4random() % 8;
NSString *selectorName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"shoot%i", random];
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName);
if ([self respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    [self performSelector:selector];
}
```

This will, by the way, generate a warning when using ARC.