# Bad receiver type 'SEL'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Objective-C and iOS (3 days old).
I am trying to work around the warning 'PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown'

```
SEL _mySelector;
id _myTarget;
NSMutableData * _myJsonData ;
[_responseTarget performSelector:_responseSelector withObject:_myJsonData]; // Warning here
```

I have changed it to this

```
    IMP imp = [_responseTarget methodForSelector:[_responseSelector withObject:_myJsonData]]; //Errors!
    void (*func)(id, SEL) = (void *)imp;
    func(_myTarget, _mySelector);
```

It errors with "Bad receiver type 'SEL'"

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: so... as newbie, what would you like to achieve exactly?

Comment: You have only a few days of experience and are already messing with the runtime? Maybe learn the basics first...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [performSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown)

Comment: Scott - if you can't help, please don't trade insults. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the warning occurs as the automatic memory management (ARC) needs to know the type and ownership of the result of a method call in order to determine how to manage any returned references to objects.

Using `performSelector` with a variable selector value does not provide this information - selector values (of type `SEL`) in Objective C do not carry type information. Without the type information the safe assumption is to do no memory management, but this might cause a leak, and so the warning.

In your case it seems you are expecting a selector with a return type of `void`, and if nothing is being returned nothing can be leaked.

Your attempt to avoid this by getting a type function pointer to the method and calling that will work, except you made a mistake. The error "Bad receiver type 'SEL'" is referring to the method call `[_responseSelector withObject:_myJsonData]` - a selector is not an object and you can't send it messages! What you appear to be trying to do is supply one argument (`_myJsonData`) to the method pre-bound into the function pointer, and the other two arguments (`_myTarget`, `_mySelector`) at the point of call. Why you should want this is unclear (maybe you're a Haskell user?).

The solution is simple, don't try to pre-bind the argument:

```
IMP imp = [_myTarget methodForSelector:_mySelector];
void (*func)(id, SEL, NSMutableData *) = (void *)imp;
func(_myTarget, _mySelector, _myJsonData);
```

However there is a different approach possible: as you know you are returning nothing (`void`) you can instruct the compiler to simply turn off the warning for the `performSelector` call:

```
    // avoid warning on performSelector - return is void so leak not possible
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
    (void)[_myTarget performSelector:_mySelector withObject:_myJsonData];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks a billion! Very well understood. Yes, Heskell background - but in this case more of a 'stupid' background not realising a selector is not an object.