# Is there something wrong with how I define a method that takes a selector as a parameter?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, selector, performselector

I have the following method:

```
- (void) broadcastSelector:(SEL)selector {
    for (id listener in [self listeners]) {
        if([listener respondsToSelector:@selector(selector)]) {
            [listener performSelector:@selector(selector)];
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm calling it in the following way:

```
[self broadcastSelector:@selector(onLoginRequestStarted)];
```

And that doesn't work. My confusion is the following:

If I hardcode the selector in the method, like the following:

```
- (void) broadcastSelector:(SEL)selector {
    for (id listener in [self listeners]) {
        if([listener respondsToSelector:@selector(onLoginRequestStarted)]) {
            [listener performSelector:@selector(onLoginRequestStarted)];
        }
    }
}
```

everything works fine. So I'm assuming something is wrong with how I call the method, or how I define the parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're double-encoding the selector inside your loop. Try this:

```
if([listener respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    [listener performSelector:selector];
}
```

Comment: If I do that I get a warning that says `PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown`. Should I ignore that?

Comment: Interesting, I've never had to actually write this type of code so I didn't know about this warning. I think [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20058585/795339) provides an explanation, and an alternative implementation that avoids the warning.

Comment: This warning makes me want to know the original intent of your code. Could you use one of the messaging mechanisms provided by Apple, such as notification center or KVO?