# How to solve "PerformSelector may cause leak because its selector is unknown"

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, performselector

I am trying to get rid of a PerformSelector warning, according to the solution described in this answer: [performSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown)

The line that is causing an issue is:

```
if ([self.target respondsToSelector:self.action]) {
    [self.target performSelector:self.action withObject:self];
}
```

I have tried to solve it by changing the code to:

```
if ([self.target respondsToSelector:self.action]) {
    SEL selector = self.action;
    IMP imp = [self.target methodForSelector:selector];
    void (*func)(id, SEL) = (void *)imp;
    func(self.target, selector);
}
```

Although it no longer reports an issue, the app crashes when this method is invoked. How can I solve this issue? This question is not a duplicate because I have read the other answer and still am unable to solve the problem.

Comment: You are probably missing the parameter to be passed to "func". Try adding third parameter to func variable while declaring and calling.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You were correct I was missing the self object. Here's what worked for me:  if ([self.target respondsToSelector:self.action]) {
        NSObject *selfOBJ = self;
        SEL selector = self.action;
        IMP imp = [self.target methodForSelector:selector];
        void (*func)(id, SEL, id) = (void *)imp;
        func(self.target, selector, selfOBJ);
    }