# Why does the warnings only appear when my iPhone is NOT connected to my Mac?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, compiler-warnings

Not a Duplicate of but the warning message is the same. I read this article and it didn't help.

[performSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown)

I am NOT using **performSelector** but I am getting the same warning as if I were.

The warning message in Xcode 6.3 is

```
 PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown
```

The code is

```
NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%tu", data.length];
NSLog(@" Expected :%lli",[response expectedContentLength]);
```

data.length should return an NSUInteger

expectedContentLength is a **long long**

When I change %tu to %zu, I get a new warning message

```
 Values of type 'NSUInteger' should not be used as format arguments; add an explicit cast to 'unsigned long' instead
```

Comment: Because in your Build Settings, you have Build Active Architecture set to YES. The warning is related to 32-bit vs 64-bit architectures and you are using invalid format arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is about the changing size of `NSUInteger` depending on the CPU architecture and probably only occurs during Release builds (which is what I understand to be "not connected to Mac") as Release builds contain all valid CPU architectures (32- and 64-bit), whereas Debug builds contain just the architecture of the device being used to debug.  (That is true if you haven't changed the *Build Settings* from the default).

As `NSUInteger` changes size, assume it's `unsigned long` and force that using a cast:

```
NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)data.length];
```

Comment: All my settings are the default.

Comment: What should I cast for expectedContentLength?

Comment: What's its data type?

Comment: long long is the data type

Comment: You shouldn't need to cast it at all.