# Perform selector may cause a leak workaround swift crash

Tags: objective-c, swift, performselector

I have a situation where I want to call a method on a target where calling perform selector gives the error: `PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown`.

To get round this I'm using the excellent solution from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown):

```
if (self.target) {
    IMP imp = [self.target methodForSelector:self.selector];
    void (*func)(id, SEL, id) = (void *)imp;
    func(self.target, self.selector, argument);
}
```

Now this code is part of a framework that I'm using in a Swift project and it's causing a crash.

If I ignore the warnings and use `[self.target performSelector:self.selector withObject:self.argument];` It works fine.

So...
I'm assuming this is to do with fundamental Swift vs. Objective-C message sending architecture. Please could someone tell me a) What's going on? b) how to get around it.

Comment: In Swift 2.0 you can just call `performSelector` directly.

Comment: The framework is in Objective-C only. The swift is the project which makes use of this framework.

Comment: Okay, well, I think I've answered the question, because _you've_ answered the questions. You have an approach that works so I don't even see what the question _is_ at this point.

Comment: The question is how can I get rid of the warning (not suppress) and have it work with swift? Also I would quite like to know the differences between the Objective-C and Swift messaging system if anyone knows.

Comment: what is `sender`? why is it different than `self.target`?

Comment: `sender` is the object that is sending the message. `self.target` is the object that is receiving the message.

Comment: @RASS: So why do you do `func(sender, self.selector, argument)`? It should be `func(self.target, self.selector, self.argument)`

Comment: Ha! Ah yes. That's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct way to send the message (assuming it takes one object parameter and returns nothing) is:

```
void (*func)(id, SEL, id) = (void (*)(id, SEL, id))objc_msgSend;
func(self.target, self.selector, self.argument);
```

Comment: Works perfectly thank you! What's the difference between what I was doing and this code? I'm assuming that my code asks the target for the method whereas here you're constructing it independently using `objc_msgSeng`? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> If I ignore the warnings and use [self.target performSelector:self.selector withObject:self.argument]; It works fine.

My advice, then, would be to suppress the warnings and just call `performSelector:...`.

Comment: There are answers to the question you cited that tell you how to suppress the warning.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of just suppressing warnings.

Comment: Well, I do give another workaround that causes the compiler to stop warning you without suppressing it artificially.