# Store references to object methods in an array (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I'm in the process of learning Objective-C and I'm trying to store method references in an array where I can loop through the array and invoke the methods. I'm coming from an interpreted language background and in a language like Ruby you could do something like the following

```
method_arr = [objectOne.method(:methodOne), objectTwo.method(:methodOne)]

method_arr.each do |m|
    m.call
end
```

The closest thing I found was using NSInvocation to achieve this with the following

```
NSMethodSignature *signature = [objectOne methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(methodOne)];
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
[invocation setSelector:@selector(methodOne)];
[invocation setTarget:objectOne];


NSArray *methodArr = @[invocation];

for (int i = 0; i < [methodArr count]; i++) {
    [methodArr[i] invoke];
}
```

Another way I found would be to use blocks which isn't referencing the methods but achieves similar results

```
NSArray *methodArr = @[^{ 
    [objectOne methodOne]
}];
```

NSInvocation seems a bit tedious for me and was wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with blocks.  When creating the array, wrap each method call in a block and add the block.

```
NSArray *calls = @[
                   ^{ [classInstance methodOne; },
                   ^{ [classInstance methodTwo; },
                   ^{ [classInstance methodThree; },
                   ^{ [classInstance methodFour; },
                 ];
```

Be aware of memory issues with this approach; specifically reference cycles.  You may want `classInstance` to be a weak reference.

You call the blocks by casting to `dispatch_block_t` and invoking.

```
((dispatch_block_t)calls[0])();
```

You can make that cleaner by typing the array.

```
NSArray<dispatch_block_t> *calls = @[
```

Now invocation is simply

```
calls[0]();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with just strings in the array. Just store the method names in the array, loop the array, convert method name string to selector with `NSSelectorFromString()`, and call `performSelector:` on the object/s. However, this may result in unwanted warning saying

> performSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown

which can be removed by wrapping your `performSelector:` code in these `pragma`'s

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
    [object performSelector: someSelector withObject: anotherObject];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

which is explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown)

Good luck, hope this was helpful!