# Why is there a warning? Can I ignore it?

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting the following warning by the ARC compiler

> performSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown

This is my code:

`[self performSelector:config.selector];`

Why do I get this warning? I understand the compiler can't check if the selector exists or not, but why would that cause a leak? And how can I change my code so that I don't get this warning anymore?

Comment: Please search on errors before posting.

Comment: @rmaddy is correct;  this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown

Comment: @bbum If it's a dupe, why did you reopen?

Comment: @rmaddy A misguided attempt to provide a modern answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @rmaddy points out, this is a duplicate of [performSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown)

---

There is a better solution than either suppressing the warning or playing other games.

Instead of using the `SEL`, use callback blocks instead.

I.e. instead of `config.selector`, go for `config.handlerBlock(...)`.

That way, you have full type safety throughout, nothing gets in the way of using ARC, and no #pragma dance to disable warnings temporarily or anything.