# Swift, for some UIViews to their overall controller when clicked

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, swift2

I have a `DotBoss:UIViewController`

There are a dozen UIView in the scene, `Dot:UIView`

(Some are direct subviews, some are further down.)

There are even **container views** in the chain between the highest controller and the Dot items.

The dozen Dot items know if they are tapped...

```
class Dot:UIView 
    {
    private var tap:UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil
    override func awakeFromNib()
        {
        tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self,
                     action: #selector(SnapDot.handleTap(_:)))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tap!)
        }
    func handleTap(g:UITapGestureRecognizer)
        {
        print("user tapped on this particular Dot...")
        }
    }
```

I want `DotBoss` to know when one of the `Dot` is tapped.

```
class DotBoss:UIViewController
  {
  func oneDotWasClicked(d:Dot)
   {
   }
  }
```

How to do this perfectly in Swift?

---

*Note* for anyone googling here, this bubbling extension is remarkably useful: https://blog.veloxdb.com/2016/05/12/bubbling-events-using-uiresponder-in-swift/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Dot (UIView) and its ultimately controlling DotBoss (UIViewController) are both *responders*, and are links along the *responder chain*. Therefore, a Dot can call a method in its DotBoss by *walking* the responder chain until it comes to the DotBoss:

```
func handleTap(g:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // ... other stuff can go here if necessary ...
    var r : UIResponder = self
    repeat { r = r.nextResponder()! } while !(r is DotBoss)
    (r as! DotBoss).oneDotWasClicked(self)
}
```

Comment: AHHH .. this actually even walks up **container views** as well.  Fascinating.

Comment: "even walks up container views" For the structure of the responder chain, see my online book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch11.html#_the_responder_chain

Comment: Of course; anyone can see that that would happen. My answer was based on the assumption made in your question, i.e. that the view is a subview of a main view controlled by a DotBoss.

Comment: For anyone googling here, a nice extension in Swift ... https://blog.veloxdb.com/2016/05/12/bubbling-events-using-uiresponder-in-swift/