# In Swift, register "anywhere" to be a delegate of a protocol

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, messaging, swift-protocols

I have a complicated view class,

```
class Snap:UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate
   {
   }
```

and the end result is the user can, let's say, pick a color...

```
protocol SnapProtocol:class
    {
    func colorPicked(i:Int)
    }
class Snap:UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate
   {
   someDelegate.colorPicked(blah)
   }
```

So who's going to handle it.

Let's say that you know for sure there is something up the responder chain, ***even walking through container views***, which is a `SnapProtocol`. If so you can use [this lovely code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37515358/294884) to call it

```
var r : UIResponder = self
repeat { r = r.nextResponder()! } while !(r is SnapProtocol)
(r as! SnapProtocol).colorPicked(x)
```

If you prefer, you can use this superlative extension

```
public extension UIResponder        // walk up responder chain
    {
    public func next<T>() -> T?
        {
        guard let responder = self.nextResponder()
            else { return nil }
        return (responder as? T) ?? responder.next()
        }
    }
```

[courtesy these guys](https://blog.veloxdb.com/2016/05/12/bubbling-events-using-uiresponder-in-swift/) and safely find any `SnapProtocol` above you,

```
 (next() as SnapProtocol?)?.colorPicked(x)
```

That's great.

But.  What if the object that wants to get the `colorPicked` is a knight-move away from you, down some complicated side chain, and/or you don't even know which object wants it.

My current solution is this, I have a singleton "game manager" -like class,

```
public class .. a singleton
    {

    // anyone who wants a SnapProtocol:
    var useSnap:SnapProtocol! = nil

    }
```

Some freaky class, anywhere, wants to eat SnapProtocol ...

```
class Dinosaur:NSObject, SnapProtocol
    {
    ....
    func colorPicked(index: Int)
        {...}
```

... so, to set that as the desired delegate, use the singleton

```
 thatSingleton.useSnap = dinosaur
```

Obviously enough, this works fine.

Note too that I could easily write a little system in the singleton, so that any number of users of the protocol could dynamically register/deregister there and get the calls.

But it has obvious problems, it's not very "pattern" and seem violently non-idiomatic.

So.  Am I really, doing this the right way in the Swift milieu?

Have I indeed confused myself, and there is some entirely different pattern I should be using in today's iOS, to send out such **"messages to anyone who wants them?"** ... maybe I shouldn't even be using a protocol?

Comment: I haven't used it yet so I can't speak for its quality, but this is a protocol-oriented, type safe notification center: https://github.com/100mango/SwiftNotificationCenter.

Comment: that's a great tip, MartinR.  Indeed that's a tidy version of what I mention above.  fascinating.

Comment: Say, in a sense that's exactly the answer to my literal question, @MartinR.  **("register “anywhere” to be a delegate of a protocol")**  Perhaps you should pop it in as an answer - it could be useful to folks googling for just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "protocol based" notification mechanism in the Swift standard
libraries or runtime. A nice implementation can be found here https://github.com/100mango/SwiftNotificationCenter. From the README:

> A Protocol-Oriented NotificationCenter which is type safe, thread safe
>   and with memory safety.
>
> - Type Safe
>
>   No more userInfo dictionary and Downcasting, just deliver the concrete
>     type value to the observer.
> - Thread Safe
>
>   You can register, notify, unregister in any thread without crash and
>     data corruption.
> - Memory Safety
>
>   SwiftNotificationCenter store the observer as a zeroing-weak
>     reference. No crash and no need to unregister manually.
>
> It's simple, safe, lightweight and easy to use for one-to-many
>   communication.

Using SwiftNotificationCenter, a (instance of a) conforming class could register itself for example like this:

```
class MyObserver: SnapProtocol {
    func colorPicked(i: Int) {
        print("color picked:", i)
    }
    init() {
        NotificationCenter.register(SnapProtocol.self, observer: self)
    }
}
```

and a broadcast notification to all conforming registered observers is
done as

```
NotificationCenter.notify(SnapProtocol.self) {
    $0.colorPicked(x)
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for the specific answer ("There is no "protocol based" notification mechanism in the Swift standard libraries or runtime") and the tremendously explanatory/useful point, good one

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37707450/function-that-takes-a-protocol-and-a-conforming-class-instance-as-parameters) was motivated by the code in SwiftNotificationCenter.

Answer (score 5):

"Send out messages to anyone who wants them" is pretty much the description of [`NSNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html).

True, it's not an API that's designed from the beginning for Swift patterns like closures, strong typing, and protocol-oriented programming. (As noted in other comments/answers, the open source [SwiftNotificationCenter](https://github.com/100mango/SwiftNotificationCenter) is a good alternative if you really want such features.)

However, `NSNotificationCenter` *is* robust and battle-hardened — it's the basis for thousands of messages that get sent around between hundreds of objects on each pass through the run loop.

---

Here's a very concise how-to for using NSNotificationCenter in Swift:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24756761/294884

Comment: I suppose you're right!   :/  Protocols are so much better than notification center though.  Perhaps one could use the notification center to set delegates of protocols  :O