# Function that takes a protocol and a conforming class (!) instance as parameters

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I am trying to figure out how to define a function which takes the following
two parameters:

1. A protocol.
2. An instance of a *class* (a *reference type*) conforming to that protocol.

For example, given

```
protocol P { }
class C : P { } // Class, conforming to P
class D { }     // Class, not conforming to P
struct E: P { } // Struct, conforming to P
```

this should compile:

```
register(proto: P.self, obj: C()) // (1)
```

but these should not compile:

```
register(proto: P.self, obj: D()) // (2)  D does not conform to P
register(proto: P.self, obj: E()) // (3)  E is not a class
```

It is easy if we drop the condition that the second parameter is a class instance:

```
func register<T>(proto: T.Type, obj: T) {
    // ...
}
```

but this would accept the struct (value type) in `(3)` as well. 
This looked promising and compiles

```
func register<T: AnyObject>(proto: T.Type, obj: T) {
    // ...
}
```

but then none of `(1)`, `(2)`, `(3)` compile anymore, e.g.

```
register(proto: P.self, obj: C()) // (1)
// error: cannot invoke 'register' with an argument list of type '(P.Protocol, obj: C)'
```

I *assume* that the reason for the compiler error is the same as in
[Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself).

Another failed attempt is

```
func register<T>(proto: T.Type, obj: protocol<T, AnyObject>) { }
// error: non-protocol type 'T' cannot be used within 'protocol<...>'
```

A viable alternative would be a function which takes as parameters

1. A *class* protocol.
2. An instance of a type conforming to that protocol.

Here the problem is how to restrict the first parameter such that only
class protocols are accepted.

**Background:** I recently stumbled over the 
[SwiftNotificationCenter](https://github.com/100mango/SwiftNotificationCenter)
project which implements a protocol-oriented, type safe notification mechanism.
It has a 
[`register`](https://github.com/100mango/SwiftNotificationCenter/blob/master/SwiftNotificationCenter/SwiftNotificationCenter.swift#L17)
method which looks like this:

```
public class NotificationCenter {

    public static func register<T>(protocolType: T.Type, observer: T) {
        guard let object = observer as? AnyObject else {
            fatalError("expecting reference type but found value type: \(observer)")
        }

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

The observers are then stored as weak references, and that's why they
must be reference types, i.e. instances of a class.
However, that is checked only at runtime, and I wonder how to make it a compile-time check.

Am I missing something simple/obvious?

Comment: Not ideal (or exactly your question), but would defining `protocol X: class {}` make this safer?

Comment: I've noticed this behaviour before – once you constrain a generic, it appears Swift will no longer allow it to take an abstract type. In this case `T` will `P`, which isn't a concrete type. I've also noticed a similar behaviour with protocol associated types (once you constrain them, they can only take concrete types) – in fact there's a [bug report about that](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1581).

Comment: @sschale: That would help if you could restrict the function to accept only class protocols (which I didn't manage either).

Comment: It's a case of GMTA, I too want to figure out some sort of extension that, well, allows you to register as a protocol listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you are trying to do directly. It has nothing to do with reference types, it's because any constraints make `T` existential so it is impossible to satisfy them at the call site when you're referencing the protocol's metatype `P.self: P.Protocol` and an adopter `C`. There is a special case when `T` is unconstrained that allows it to work in the first place.

By far the more common case is to constrain `T: P` and require `P: class` because just about the *only* thing you can do with an arbitrary protocol's metatype is convert the name to a string. It happens to be useful in this narrow case but that's it; the signature might as well be `register<T>(proto: Any.Type, obj: T)` for all the good it will do.

In theory Swift could support constraining to metatypes, ala `register<T: AnyObject, U: AnyProtocol where T.Type: U>(proto: U, obj: T)` but I doubt it would be useful in many scenarios.