# In Swift: How to create a generic method with two generics, one constrained to the other

Tags: swift, generics, methods, protocols

Check the following method definition:

```
func method<T,K>(protocol: K, object: T) where T:AnyObject, K:Protocol {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

- `T` is an `AnyObject`
- `K` is a `Protocol`

Now I would like to add an additional constraint: the object of type `T` must implement the protocol `K`.

Something like this:

```
func method<T,K>(protocol: K, object: T) where T:AnyObject, K:Protocol, T:K {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Note the `T:K` added in the `where` clausule.

When I try this, I get the error:

`Type 'T' constrained to a non-protocol, non-class type 'K'`

Is this achievable somehow?

Comment: This *might* be a similar problem as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37707450/function-that-takes-a-protocol-and-a-conforming-class-instance-as-parameters.