# Is there any way of asking an iOS view which of its children has first responder status?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiresponder, responder-chain

In Mac OS X, you can find the first responder like this:

```
[[self window] firstResponder]
```

Is there any way of doing it in iOS?  Or do you need to enumerate the child controls and send an `isFirstResponder`message to each one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would need to iterate over all of the child controls and test the `isFirstResponder` property. When you encounter `TRUE`, break out of the loop.

```
UIView *firstResponder;
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) //: caused error
{
    if (view.isFirstResponder)
    {
        firstResponder = view;
        break;
    }
}
```

---

**BETTER SOLUTION**

See [Jakob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14135456/483349).

Comment: This snippet only searches direct descendants of a view, but wont find the first responder when it is nested deeper.

Answer (score 254):

I really like [VJK's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10358135/322427), but as MattDiPasquale suggests it seems more complex than necessary. So I wrote this simpler version:

#### Objective-C

**UIResponder+FirstResponder.h:**

```objectivec
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIResponder (FirstResponder)
    +(id)currentFirstResponder;
@end
```

**UIResponder+FirstResponder.m:**

```objectivec
#import "UIResponder+FirstResponder.h"

static __weak id currentFirstResponder;

@implementation UIResponder (FirstResponder)

+(id)currentFirstResponder {
    currentFirstResponder = nil;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(findFirstResponder:) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
    return currentFirstResponder;
}

-(void)findFirstResponder:(id)sender {
   currentFirstResponder = self;
}

@end
```

#### Swift 4

```
import UIKit

extension UIResponder {

    private static weak var _currentFirstResponder: UIResponder?

    static var currentFirstResponder: UIResponder? {
        _currentFirstResponder = nil
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.findFirstResponder(_:)), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)

        return _currentFirstResponder
    }

    @objc func findFirstResponder(_ sender: Any) {
        UIResponder._currentFirstResponder = self
    }
}
```

I also made it a class method since that seemed to make more sense. You can now find the first responder like so: `[UIResponder currentFirstResponder]`

---

Comment: This is brilliantly simple, well done.

Comment: Wouldn't using `UIResponder *` make more sense than `id`?

Comment: @StevenFisher I'm pretty sure that the first responder is always a view, so maybe `UIView*` would make even more sense. (eg. a view controller would be in the responder chain, but it can't be the first responder -- the first responder would be the view it controls) But to be honest, I didn't think too deeply about the return type. Using `id` avoids having to use explicit casts.

Comment: instancetype would fit well :)

Comment: Ok, gonna use this in all of my projects from now on, neat snippet!

Comment: @Arcank I think that `instancetype` is not a good idea here. Imagine calling `[UITextView currentFirstResponder]`, there is no guarantee that the first responder is actually a `UITextView`. `UIResponder *` as return value should be fine.

Comment: fwiw: View controllers **can** become first responders. All you need to do is to return `YES` from `-canBecomeFirstResponder`. This is great for input accessory views that are always on screen or handling shortcuts even when no view is focussed, etc. As such, using `UIView *` would be wrong here.

Comment: Great solution! I came up with [something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24639472/35690), but instead of using a static variable, I subclassed UIEvent. This makes it safer (e.g. if you have multiple threads, or if you have nested function calls, it'll still work correctly).

Comment: @Senseful Making `+currentFirstResponder` reentrant is pointless if you call it only from the main thread. And you really shouldn't call it from a background thread. UIKit is not thread safe.

Comment: wish I could upvote this answer several times.

Comment: Here is a Swift implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27140764/385979

Comment: Doesn't work in `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, since its not firstResponder yet when the notification handler called...

Comment: Doesn't work at least on iOS9. I put focus into `TextField` which is in the `scrollview`. After I check `firstResponder` in the way described and get ScrollView as the first responder.
At the same time
`[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject] valueForKey:@"firstResponder"]` gives TextField.

Comment: @malex I have some text fields on a uitableview inside a cell, the method above works even on iOS 9, i haven't tried a scrollview, but since the tableview inherits from scrollview, I think it should also work?. Have you found other instances where this solution doesn't work?

Comment: It's won't work at least if responder is UITableViewCell (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24343989/95060).

Comment: Highly recommended to prefix objc category methods with your class prefix (for ex `abc_currentFirstResponder`).

Comment: anyone tell me how can i use this code in non ARC project?

Comment: Just a gotcha, if you have custom UIControl's (i.e. a UITextField subclass) and implement `override open func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool` then ensure you return true for the action this solution uses, i.e. `if action == #selector(findFirstResponder(sender:)) {return true}`

Answer (score 27):

I wrote a category on `UIResponder` to find the first responder

```
@interface UIResponder (firstResponder)
- (id) currentFirstResponder;
@end
```

and

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import "UIResponder+firstResponder.h"

static char const * const aKey = "first";

@implementation UIResponder (firstResponder)

- (id) currentFirstResponder {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(findFirstResponder:) to:nil from:self forEvent:nil];
    id obj = objc_getAssociatedObject (self, aKey);
    objc_setAssociatedObject (self, aKey, nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
    return obj;
}

- (void) setCurrentFirstResponder:(id) aResponder {
    objc_setAssociatedObject (self, aKey, aResponder, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
}

- (void) findFirstResponder:(id) sender {
    [sender setCurrentFirstResponder:self];
}

@end
```

Then in any class that derives from a `UIResponder` you can get the first responder by calling

```
UIResponder* aFirstResponder = [self currentFirstResponder];
```

but remember to import the UIResponder category interface file first!

This uses documented API's so there should be no app store rejection issues.

Comment: Using `-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]` is neat! :) But, instead of using an associated object to reference `firstResponder`, why not just use a static variable since there'll only be one `firstResponder` at a time?

Comment: Oh that's clever! I couldn't make send of your `sendAction:` until I read the docs. That must be the only part of iOS's APIs that actually gives direct access to the first responder.

Comment: just returns the view that asked the currentFirstResponder. When i check the responder if it's first responder as expected it say no

Comment: I know this is old, and there is an accepted (and much more upvoted) answer based off this one, but this was an excellent solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

If you need first responder just so you can ask it to resign its status, here is an approach to get any to resign. UIView has a method that will iterate through all of UIViews subviews and ask any that are first responder to resign.

```
[[self view] endEditing:YES];
```

Here is a [link to Apple's UIView Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW100)
"This method looks at the current view and its subview hierarchy for the text field that is currently the first responder. If it finds one, it asks that text field to resign as first responder. If the force parameter is set to YES, the text field is never even asked; it is forced to resign."

Comment: I don't think OP wants to force it to resign first responder, just to find the first responder.

Comment: Nevertheless, this is a good place for people to discover that snippet.