# UIWebView Insert Text?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Is there method similar as

> `[textfield Inserttext:NSString]`

in UIWebView?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Simulate sending data to a web page that you loaded via `loadRequest`, or do you have some static HTML that you loaded via `loadHTMLString` that you want to change? In short, there's no direct analog to `insertText`, but it's probably more important to understand what you're trying to do, rather than what methods are there.

Comment: Hi Rob.. Sorry It's NSString :)
Actually i'm trying to send text to UIWebView active textbox from custom keyboard.

Comment: @Chan You can try JavaScript injection using the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method of `UIWebView`.

Comment: Actually i have some javascript function to send data from custom Keyboard.It's perfect on normal website.It can show any text sent from custom keyboard.
but my problem was my javascript cannot detect facebook comment plugin textbox.

Comment: This facebook comment plugin is more complicated than i think.It's use iframe and some funny funny thing. 
My javascript cannot detect on this funny funny thing.
That's why i m looking perfect input method on any website, any textbox.

Comment: In that case you should have added that as well in the question. Also you might have to post the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` part. That will help others to look into this.

Comment: /*
var txtarea = document.activeElement;
txtarea.value='sometext from KB';
*/

Comment: It's main part of my script. I remove other unnecessary thing.
get the current activeElement
and assign value to this element.

Comment: @Chan I need your help. I have a same case. I have set my custom keyboard to UITextField and UITextView. but I cann't integrate with browser.Will you plz help me ?

Comment: Hi Hi Ren, use javascript injection for uiwebview text

Comment: @Chan Actually I have never used javascript. can you please help me out for this

Answer (score 0):

First:

Get the first responder. [Get first responder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029267/is-there-any-way-of-asking-an-ios-view-which-of-its-children-has-first-responder/14135456#14135456)

Second:

```
id responder = [UIResponder currentFirstResponder];
UITextRange *selectedTextRange = responder.selectedTextRange;
[responder replaceRange: textRange withText: @"text"];
```