# Detect lost focus on UITextView which is still the first responder

Tags: ios, objective-c, events, hid

I'm trying to integrate an external scanner with HID interface, so I use a UITextView to capture the scanner data (A HID device is like a keyboard), and the screen has several nested views, I show a table view with a master-detail in a subview.

I use a UISwitch (with label "Use external scanner") to force the focus on my UITextView, If I enable the switch the scanner is correctly read and It works Ok.

The hierarchy It's similar to:

- Scanner view (contains the UITextView with the UISwitch and some other fields)

  - Table view with a list (a subview of the scanner view)
  - Detailed view

My application use an story board, my problem is that after I force the focus on the UITextView, if I touch on the table view and a detailed view appears, the focus seems lost and the scanner is no longer read. I've checked with a UITimer that runs every 2 seconds that the UITextView is still the first responder (I use this answer to find the first responder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14135456/661140), but for some reason is not responding.

I've tried to detect when the focus is lost using `- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView` but It doesn't work

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (textView == _hiddenTextExternalScannerTextView)
    {
        NSLog(@"Text view has lost the focus in textFieldDidEndEditing");
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the UITextView is not responding to keyboard events ? Is there any way to detect when the field is no longer responding ?

I did the same test without the HID device, only the internal keyboard, and when I browse out of the field, the keyboard is dismissed, but the field is still detected like the first responder.

Comment: in storyboard select your tableView and in the attributes inspector, there is a field about keyboard, be sure than you have selected do not dismiss

Comment: @OnikIV, when I use the HID device the keyboard doesn't appear so It's no dismissed, It's similar to a bluetooth keyboard.