# Get UITextField from Keyboard Notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

I am trying to get `UITextField` that on which the observer `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` is being called.

My Observer is in `appdelegate` and I have several UIViewControllers that have several UITextFields in them, in short I don't know current First Responder.

How can I get the first responder inside my Method that is fired upon the keyboard notification `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`?

Comment: If you only need to know what text field just got the focus, consider handling the `UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification`. It passes the text field in the `object` parameter.

Comment: do you need to make some changes on your project when UITextField called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible to deduce from `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` simply because it contains following information only. However, check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029267/is-there-any-way-of-asking-an-ios-view-which-of-its-children-has-first-responder/14135456#14135456) which has a brilliant solution on how to get the current first responder.

> NSConcreteNotification 0x7ff14d1ac0d0 {name =
>   UIKeyboardWillShowNotification; userInfo = {
>       UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey = 7;
>       UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey = "0.25";
>       UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {320, 216}}";
>       UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 676}";
>       UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 460}";
>       UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 568}, {320, 216}}";
>       UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 352}, {320, 216}}";
>       UIKeyboardIsLocalUserInfoKey = 1; }}