# How do I get the size of the keyboard and the CGFrame of the selected UITextField at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikit, nsnotificationcenter

I'm populating a vertical `UIScrollView` with many `UITextField` fields dynamically on runtime. The problem I have is that the keyboard will hide the fields that are in the area where it will appear, this may include the field I'm editing.

I tried [KeyboardManagement](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7) solution from the apple documentation and also tried with notifications on the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and `textFieldDidEndEditing` but the problem in both cases is that the `keyboardWillShow` notification comes first sometimes, and in that case it doesn't let me know which field is the one being edited.

I have this code in a class that implements the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, each object of this class holds a reference to one of those fields and works as it's delegate

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.activeTextfield = self.valueTextField
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.activeTextfield = nil
}
```

The `activeTextfield` variable is a weak reference to the variable in the `UIViewController` where all of this happens. In that view controller I have the following code

```
class MyClass: UIViewController {
    var activeTextfield: CustomTextField! // This is the variable I was talking about on the previous paragraph

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }
            guard let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }

            let keyboardFrame = keyboardSize.cgRectValue
            let textFieldFrame = activeTextfield!.frame // activeTextfield sometimes is nil because this notification happens before the previous code block

            if textFieldFrame.origin.y + textFieldFrame.size.height > keyboardFrame.origin.y {
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardFrame.height
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }
            guard let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }

            let keyboardFrame = keyboardSize.cgRectValue

            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardFrame.height
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can force the `UITextField` delegate methods to be called before the keyboard notification?

Is this the correct way to handle this kind of situation?

If not, how should I handle it?

Thanks

Comment: It's not the best solution but it simple enough. Once keyboardWillShow notification fires you need to find firstResponder in your current view hierarchy. You can do it the following way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/get-the-current-first-responder-without-using-a-private-api
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14135456/6388105

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in your question:

> the problem in both cases is that the keyboardWillShow notification
>   comes first sometimes, and in that case it doesn't let me know which
>   field is the one being edited

As per the [sequence of events](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/ManageTextFieldTextViews/ManageTextFieldTextViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH10-SW15) described in apple's documentation, `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` is the first delegate method called.

So, you can

1. implement `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` in the delegate to set your active text field,  instead of `textFieldDidBeginEditing` (make sure you `return true` from textFieldShouldBeginEditing to allow editing)
2. use `keyboardDidShowNotification` instead of `keyboardWillShowNotification`.

This will ensure you have your `UITextField` marked before getting the keyboard frame / details.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so fairly simply by doing the following. First add notification observers in your view will appear.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)        
    // Keyboard notification
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
```

Then in your selector function you can have something like this

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue,
            let currentTextField = view.getSelectedTextField() {

        let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
        let textFieldFrame = currentTextField.superview?.convert(currentTextField.frame, to: nil)            
        }
    }
}
```

And your `getSelectedTextField()` extension looks like this

```
// Inside UIView Extension 
// Get currently active textfield
func getSelectedTextField() -> UITextField? {

    let totalTextFields = getTextFieldsInView(view: self)

    for textField in totalTextFields{
        if textField.isFirstResponder{
            return textField
        }
    }
    return nil
}

    func getTextFieldsInView(view: UIView) -> [UITextField] {

        var totalTextFields = [UITextField]()

        for subview in view.subviews as [UIView] {
            if let textField = subview as? UITextField {
                totalTextFields += [textField]
            } else {
                totalTextFields += getTextFieldsInView(view: subview)
            }
        }
        return totalTextFields
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define tag property to your textFields and check in
`textFieldDidBeginEditing` and `textFieldDidEndEditing` what `UITextField` was called.

Comment: All I need is the textfield object, which I get as a parameter of those methods, but I don't know how to send it to the ViewController before the keyboard notification (because in the method called for that notification, I decide if I should shift the screen up or not based on that textfield's coordinates)

Comment: Why are you use self.view.frame.origin.y for screen up? You scrollView methods for this setContentOffset or scrollRectToVisible.

Comment: To move the frame of the main UIView up