# UITableViewCell and resignFirstResponder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITableView` containing in each cell a `UITextField`. When the user clicks on the `UITextField`, as expected, the keyboard will popup.

I have implemented in my delegate `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method to dismiss the keyboard with `resignFirstResponder` sent to the last `UITextField` used.

Everything works ok if the cell with the last `UITextField` used is displayed.

Now, if I scroll down to bottom of the tableview and press on a row, then the `resignFirstResponder` is sent to a hidden `UITextField` and will not hide the keyboard. It doesn't throw an error also.

How can I hide the keyboard in such cases?

Comment: why don't you use the return key ?

Comment: Keyboard type is Number Pad...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) and put the

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

method in one of the callback functions. I particulary prefer:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Comment: - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField; is not called at all in my case.

Comment: This method is called when the return/done button is clicked. If this does not suit you exactly you should choose a callback for another action.

Comment: My keyboard type is Number Pad, so I don't have return/done button. And I don't need it for anything else, so I think the method will not work...

Comment: Have you read my last comment? My keyboard type is Number Pad. There is no return, done, go and so on... button on the bottom right side. Only delete button.

Comment: For example there is `-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`. This is called whenever a new character is typed. Or checkout [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/how-do-i-legally-get-the-current-first-responder-on-the-screen-on-an-iphone). Or you should consider using `UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation`. However, if you are not able to close your keyboard through delegation, maybe you should change your code design a bit.

Comment: Thanks. That post solved it. I just had to add [self.view endEditing:YES];

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling `endEditing:YES` method of the `UITextField`?

Comment: This should make the first responder to resign. It doesn't matter keyboard type. Not sure this will work, but you can try :)

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Not with endEditing or setEditing (like you initially mentioned).

Comment: setEditing was wrong because editing property is read-only, just made a bit of confusion...

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)hidekey:(id) sender{

[textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

if you using  Interface builder then checked outlet of text field and in .m file use above function and define for that text field. It will work.

Comment: what u want to ask? i give this for hid keyboard.

Comment: Please explain better... What do you mean by "if you using Interface builder then checked outlet of text field"? Especially "then checked outlet of text field"?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this tutorial to [Create a return Key for UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad](http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key) ! This should save a lot of time for you.