# Capture text from UITextField in instance variable when another UIButton is pressed on UIView

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a few UITextFields (within UITableViewCells) on my UIView with a "Save" UIButton. I want to do some basic validation on the UITextFields when the user clicks the "Save" button.

I have overridden textFieldDidEndEditing to save each of my UITextField data to an instance variable; however, if a user clicks the save button before either clicking the "Return" button of the UIKeyboard or clicking on another UITextField the data in my last UITextField is never saved to my instance variable and validation always fails.

I am looking for a way to trigger an "onBlur" (I know that's a JS thing)-type event to save my string in UITextField to my instance variable.

I've looked through the UITextFieldDelegate Protocol and I do not see anything like this.

Is there a method I may be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to trigger `textFieldDidEndEditing` on your `UITextField`, you will need to call

```
[_txt resignFirstResponder];
```

were `_txt` is your `UITextField`

Please note that if you dont have a reference to _txt and you need to find the first responder in order to resign it
You could use the solution from this question [Get the current first responder without using a private API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/how-do-i-legally-get-the-current-first-responder-on-the-screen-on-an-iphone)

Then instead of calling

```
[_txt resignFirstResponder];
```

you would call

```
[self.view findAndResignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: well... there is the rub... since my UITextField is in a UITableViewCell... I don't really know how I am going to get access to my _txt within the cell...

Comment: nevermind... I can probably set the _txt as an instance variable and check it there... let me see about that

Comment: @ElGuapo ok, please check the updated answer it contains a solution to resign a responder without having a reference to it :)

Comment: No need, pleasure helping you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this
// if we encounter a newline character return

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{   
    // enter closes the keyboard
    if ([string isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

which will trigger

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    // Call webservice
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)